# Add a policy and a tag for self-study / homework

Tags: discussion, questions, homework

If you go and read the [self-study wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) at CV ([Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)), you will find it to be well conceived and written. I feel that this would be a valuable addition to Stack Overflow, both in the FAQ/Wiki to allow us to point to, as well as in the form of an additional tag. I have included the tag `self-study` with this question, so that is there. I am aware of the burninated `homework` tag. I have read much of that thread, and understand frustration amongst Meta Stack Overflow members about how the tag did not solve any problems. I don't believe that the tag itself is the solution, but rather the consistent use of the policy (e.g., the CV example). Even if posters don't see it, through both active promotion by all of you, as well as the increasing over time rise of these links (and the tag), normalization to some degree of expectation can occur.

I see a great many self-study/homework questions, many well intended (and, regrettably, some not so much). It would be good to be able to filter on these and give users a structured, consistent framework in which to seek help.

EDIT: I should have added, the two suggestions are independent enough to be independently implemented. If people are against the tag, that doesn't mean that there shouldn't be a new `stackoverflow.com/help/self-study/`.

Related threads include [Please clarify the policy on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions), [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: That would be a meta tag. Meta tags have been deemed inherently "Not Useful".

Comment: How would questions tagged [tag:homework] differ significantly from other questions, but still be valid and on-topic?

Comment: Very hard to see the point.  We're all programmers here, a self-study tag would be like [coffee] or [breathing].

Comment: We already had a homework tag years ago, it wasn't helpful.

Comment: The wiki might be OK-ish (that can go with all the other help-topics that are seldom read by new users) but the tag isn't a good idea. Everything that gives the slightest impression that you can dump your homework/study assignment here should not be endorsed.

Comment: Please see the forest despite the trees. The proposed tag is not the solution, but rather a means to the end of having a referable policy. The important solution is to have something that users can be pointed to.

Comment: Policy: if you want to answer a homework question, answer it. If you want to up/downvote, vote accordingly. If you want to close it, and there is a reason that fits, then close it. Same goes for all other questions.

Comment: We've got tonnes of stuff to point users to, lots of reading material; unfortunately users just don't read. Putting more information out there that they aren't going to read isn't really all that useful. Better to just close off-topic questions and downvote bad on-topic questions.

Comment: Your proposal seems to focus on the users asking homework questions. Those users are not the problem. The problem is that their questions and answers generated by them are at best useful for them but might not have so much value for future visitors which is the success driver for SO.

Comment: I agree with your point on utility of many of those questions, @rene. What the CV wiki provides, I find, is a written reason why the posters question is getting slammed, down voted, etc. It should raise the bar. I find myself liberally inserting [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/). But I am not getting good vibes from the crowd here. I'll let it plummet some more and then delete the question.

Comment: We did have one way back in the day. Would reviving the `Homework` tag be something that anyone adds to their favorites? Would it help get those questions answered, or would it create a newbie ghetto on the fringes of SO? How long would it last before someone came to meta to complain about the endless stream of people copy-pasting their assignments into the question box and pressing submit? How long would it take before someone gives up and requests a burnination? Could the tag stand by itself on the question? (Please don't read that as confrontational, I'm just being terse. Not enough space.)

Answer (score 34):

The policy is universal:

## Your question must be on-topic for the site.

The fact that it's a homework question or it's a self-study question is ***irrelevant.***  Vote on the question on its merits of quality alone, not what its general subject matter is.

Comment: These questions could be on-topic or not for SO, regardless of how they approached solving their problem. The link to CV encourages posters to approach their self-study in a certain way, to demonstrate that they have attempted to understand their problem. I was never suggesting that we should down or up vote questions based on their self-study status. I was suggesting that the CV framework is a written set of guidelines that encourages posters to approach their help-seeking in a certain way.

Comment: How does this differ from *any other question* on the site?  What would this framework bring to the table that we don't already enforce?

Comment: clearly, from everyone else's reaction, nothing. I bow to the force of the roar of the crowd. The question can't be deleted by me because it has an answer.

Comment: @ShawnMehan Why would you want to delete it? Someone else wondering about the same thing at some point in the future might use the search function, find it, and see that it's not a feature the community wants to add.

Comment: i forgot to add tags before I posted. But I'll remember. `<asbestos longjohns>` required.