# Is it okay for students to ask Stack Overflow to do their homework?

Tags: discussion, homework

I think it is good learning for them. But what do you think?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking about whether students should be allowed to ask "gimme teh codez" questions? If so, I think that the answer should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Yes basically. Like the teacher gave them questions. And they cant do it by reading books or lecture notes. So they ask in SO. is it ok? does it breach any SO rules?

Comment: This is already addressed in multiple places in the FAQ and help center. See: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236), for starters. The Software Engineering SE FAQ has a rather good [Open letter to students with homework](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) as well.

Comment: _does it breach any SO rules?_
~ ~
It might.
[Our cc-wiki licensing, while intentionally permissive, does **require** attribution.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required)
Thus, as long as you tell your teacher:
_I asked this question at Stack Overflow and here is the answer
I received from N.N._, then you don't break 
[Stack Overflow's legal terms](https://stackoverflow.blog/legal).
See
[How to ask and answer homework questions | Be aware of school policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823).
See also [Caveat emptor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378440).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## No.  Students *need* to do their *own* homework.

### They will learn nothing if we do their homework for them, and it's not our responsibility to teach them.

Comment: good to know. so what should we do? downvote?

Comment: If [it's not otherwise a good question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308252/1079354), it's fine to downvote/vote to close as too broad.  The question being homework related *alone* doesn't mean it's bad.

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to make the whole answer bold.

Comment: @DonaldDuck:  So you haven't seen [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September), I take it.  It gets tiring to have to explain to students here that no, you can't just dump your assignment here and we'll happily code it up.  Besides, this answer offers the *least* ambiguity on the stance of the community.

Comment: Exactly. Oh and guess what? I've actually been grilled a few times by other members who think the contrary when I told them that Stack isn't a school nor a tutorial site, go figure.