# Caveat emptor. Making students aware they cannot delete their homework questions

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, new-users, homework

It's the usual trick of people asking a homework question, then as soon as it's answered, they delete it. For example:

[How can you put 20 turtles on a circle in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946721/how-can-you-put-20-turtles-on-circle-in-python)

[Visualize a sparse matrix using Python Turtle graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157237/visualize-a-sparse-matrix-using-python-turtle-graphics)

[Turn left, right, accelerate or decelerate with Python turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195585/turn-left-right-accelerate-or-decelerate-with-python-turtle)

[Generate picture using object implementation of the turtle graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867656/generate-picture-using-object-implementation-of-the-turtle-graphics)

They can only do this if there's only one answer, and the only answer has no upvotes. Owners cannot delete their questions with multiple answers or upvoted answers.

If you are not permitted to post homework questions, then don't post them. For many educational institutions, obtaining this type of assistance amounts to academic misconduct. It's the student's responsibility not to outsource their homework. The fact that many questions are deleted so quickly leads one to think that the questioner already knows this.

### Check with your teacher before asking homework questions on Stack Overflow

It's not okay to delete useful content off the site that others have put their time and effort into just to try to cover your tracks. As evidenced by the examples above, the posts will be restored. [You've granted the network an irrevocable license to the content](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

> As noted in the Stack Exchange Terms of Service and in the footer of every page, all user contributions are licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike. Proper attribution is required if you republish any Stack Exchange content.
>
> Please read the terms of service and the full legal text of the license carefully for more details on how your content can be used.

This is something all users agree to before posting.

If you have changed your mind about a post, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Comment: @Shog9 thanks. I was thinking of polishing this and maybe appending it to the faq on homework questions.

Comment: Aren’t faqs still supposed to be questions? With an answer? This reads like an answer with no question...

Comment: It seems in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53950688/7505395)  [cdlane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5771269/cdlane) saw the same code multiple times - the user of the OP of that answer has only one question in total ... so multi-accounting in addition to educational disbehaviour with his homework?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Not necessarily. Sometimes students get the same pre-written code they need to modify/extend

Comment: Playing devil's advocate for a second... if the site _allows_ them to delete the question when there's only one answer... why shouldn't they?  Shouldn't the rules instead be changed to disallow question deletion if _any_ non-negative answers are present?  If not, what's the justification/intended use case for the ability to be able to delete such questions in the first place?

Comment: shouldn't self-deleted questions with upvoted answers raise a flag somewhere? at the mods, or even in an undelete queue?

Comment: there is a nice letter to creative homeworkers on softwareengineering: [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) that I sometimes refer to - but thats one or two steps before deletion of the question

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's a discussion. Not sure where it will lead. Hopefully some homework posters will read it. Or I can at least link to it when undeleting their posts ;)

Comment: This is worth discussing but I'd rather we finally agree to stamp out answers in comments! Those are really getting out of hand. Everybody seems to have forgotten why SO was created, literally.

Comment: The ability to delete a question with any answer should be a privilege. Not sure why it isn't.

Comment: How do you propose to make the student aware of this?

Comment: The postings are anonymous, so this is an absolute no-issue.

Comment: @AndrewMorton that's the million dollar question. I don't know.

Comment: Absolutely amazed the new question template/wizard/whatever-it's-called-now hasn't been mentioned yet. Obvious place for this guidance to go.

Comment: @jpmc26 excellent point. Please write an answer?

Comment: I'm with @Will.  Deleting a question that has at least one answer clearly affects more people than the owner of the question.  It should require privilege, at least if it has any answers with nonnegative score.  I'd say around 125 rep -- that being the point where the OP would be able to DV answers in support of deleting the question.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295420/how-to-cope-with-complaints-from-tutors-who-want-to-fight-cheaters

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think instead we should post a big legal warning in a confirmation modal when users try to submit their first 1 to 3 questions (maybe their first 1 to 3 questions with code only?), saying something like

> Are you sure? **You will no longer own or have total control over this content or any code you post once you submit**. It will be licensed under CC By-SA 3.0, and other users, as well as the website itself, can prevent you from removing it, and can make edits to it as necessary. (with a link to that license).

Something broader like that could stop not only people who want to get a quick HW answer and then delete, but may also stop a lot of the other self-vandalism we see... some users who try to self delete honestly don't know, and this could also have a modest reduction in DMCA claims for such well-meaning but ignorant posters of such code. Finally, this could ward off a little bit of other general vandalism we see by just serving as a reminder that other users have the ability to preserve and edit content.

Comment: They *do* still own the content.  Although they are indeed giving up some control over the content that *they still own*.  But while you'd need to have the lawyers look over the wording.  The other major risk is that basically every site (including SE) already has the "you agree to the terms of service" popup when joining the site.  People have been trained to not read them (not that it means we shouldn't try anyway).

Comment: DMCA? wtf? They use this as a "tool" to try to get their questions disappear?

Comment: @iBug Askers typically do not, but many posts get deleted by mods to comply with DMCA requests from companies (people posting interview questions or other protected IP). Seeing such a warning may help them realize 'hmm, this is sensitive code, maybe I shouldn't post it if I won't be able to delete it immediately...'

Comment: @iBug Many people *don't* actually have the right to apply the CC-SA license to the content that they post (this is in fact common in the case of homework, if they're just regurgitating a homework problem that may not be their original content to post), so a DMCA claim is in fact warranted.  You'll also sometimes see *the educational institution* submit a DMCA claim to keep their proprietary homework assignments private.

Comment: well I guess it doesn't hurt to display this warning. Even if a lot of people won't give a damn about it. It may deter some indiduhals

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes that's the issue. we can't force people to care.

Comment: I'm not sure that students will understand the implications.

Comment: @jpmc26 If you mean the implication that they can't delete their question, then they probably would not understand the implications of any such message about not being able to delete their homework. If you mean the implication that it is being posted under another license, the text I chose intentionally leads with an agnostic warning about not being able to delete your question regardless of reason.

Comment: How about making it a checkbox instead of a big warning? Of course, people can still ignore it, but the mechanism is already implemented for when you're in a team and you're posting a public question, and it also won't pop up every time you try to post the question just because you tried to fix a mistake. "`[ ]` I understand that I, after posting this question, will not have any control over it anymore, as it will be released publicly under the [CC BY-SA 3.0] license. I understand that I may not be able to delete this post, if the Stack Overflow community disagrees with that decision."

Comment: @EKons Sure, that would work just as well, perhaps better. I consider it an implementation detail, though. Of course it is not likely that SO will act on anything suggested on Meta these days, it's worth gathering a consensus for when the day comes they hire an employee who cares again.

Answer (score 22):

Is...this...really...a problem for us?

The point is made that these questions aren't the highest value and if they disappear, then that implies that the system works - no one upvoted the content which would've prevented self-deletion, so no one felt that the content was worth preserving.  A counter to that could be that the deletion happened immediately after an answer was posted, and while that could ruffle feathers with people wasting their time, I'm...just not that convinced that this is going to be something that words alone can solve.

The only real thing that could address something like this - if it were an issue - would be to accelerate the rate of q-bans.  People can't post their homework questions and delete them if they can't post them in the first place.

Comment: agree re deletion of the low quality questions. But the ones I'm referring to are not low quality.

Comment: @YvetteColomb well then you've seriously triggered the dark side of the meta because all the questions you linked to are now in the minus...

Comment: @Gimby oh no. They didn't start off like that. Honestly the meta effect drives me crazy. I deliberately do not vote on questions linked in meta.

Comment: they say [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601) that the rate of q-bans is already accelerated: "deleting a question right after someone posts an answer to it. This... pattern is seen as so overtly hostile that it does impose a pretty stiff penalty..."

Comment: @YvetteColomb Why do you think they're useful questions?  They're mostly just dumps of code with fairly poor descriptions of a problem, and someone posts a fixed version of their code with fewer bugs.  How are those questions going to help any future visitors?  Who's going to have the same problem *be able to find those questions*, and have the answers help them solve their own problem?  (And also not be able to solve their problem with any other readily accessible information out there.)  It seems pretty unlikely for those questions.

Comment: but some people create (fake) accounts all the  just to workaround the Q-ban. Where I agree is: if people delete when I have answered, _I_ lost my time. I should have detected (that's the sixth sense I'm talking about in my answer) that it was a waste of time from the start :) If the question is good, I can still request undeletion from SOCVR or other

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  This is what I want to get at when I say "accelerate the rate of a q-ban".  Delete a question after an answer is posted?  Rate-limited for 3 months.  Multiple accounts doing that from the same IP?  Rate-limit any new accounts for the next five months.

Answer (score 17):

Not sure if this was intended as a question but there's an "answer" box so:

When a question asker tries to delete their question which has answers, a warning pops up. Maybe turn that into a blocker even if no answer is accepted yet (and at least one has a zero score i.e. not all answers are downvoted): "you cannot delete your question because there are answers". If OP really wants to delete, they can always flag for moderation.

If OP "defaces" their post like we often see with blurb like "deleted deleted deleted", then it usually trips Smokey or some bot and someone usually rolls back, so not a crucial issue either.

That, or some queue mechanism for deleted questions with zero-score answers where 10k+ reviewers could choose to edit/undelete interesting questions/questions with interesting answers.

That, or a sixth sense from the future answerers on too broad/non-researched homework questions: avoid like the plague (and 1) it's not because it's vaguely upvoted that it's good/adds value 2) if the question is closed as too broad, it can be deleted eventually even with upvoted/accepted answers)

Comment: reputation hunters won't avoid easy homework questions

Comment: You cannot delete the question if it has upvoted answers: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Comment: oh thanks. The message appears when there are _answers_ then. Will edit

Comment: @Cœur What really puzzles me isn't users answering homework questions, but that those homework Q/A are often upvoted sometimes even with score > 5. Those upvoters are a genuine mystery.

Comment: @liliscent classmates?

Comment: @Cœur No idea. Maybe some users enjoy upvoting homework related stuff. A "homework contributor" badge sounds promising...

Comment: @liliscent, high rep users can vote to delete questions with negative scores (on the basis that the question adds 'no value whatsoever' to the site, probably true for many homework dumps), so it may be in the interest of rep hunters to upvote the questions to prevent deletion and consequent loss of rep for their answers.  I'm just surmising though, I have no evidence this actually happens.

Comment: I have thought about how to prevent it. The issue is, there's more questions with answers that need questioner self deletion as they're not good questions, but have accrued answers. Currently we're relying on the posters of the answers to raise flags that the post has been deleted.  Oh and yeh, it's supposed to be a discussion, so answers are good

Comment: @snakecharmerb "high rep users can vote to delete questions with negative scores" yes but when they are closed. And upvoting a closed question just delay the deletion if someone (or some room :)) sets their mind to it.

Comment: @liliscent, the voting pattern is really clear for both answer and question. On question it act as a notification system. Every new answer from a low reputation will match an upvote on the question. While hight rep user answer will gather good amount of upvote both from front page and other answers. Low rep answer will use upvote as notification system. Reaching 1-2 upvote.

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly clear what you trying to solve here - commonly such "write my homework" questions are of low quality and really should not stay on the site. Such questions don't deserve answers but some people are eager to provide them when they should not. Removal of the question *may* hint such contributors to slow down and skip bad questions. I really don't see how question being deleted as soon as answer is provided is bad for a site as whole.

Indeed this is "not welcoming" behavior toward answerer on questioner's side, but I don't think we are ever concerned about that side.

Indeed this may be against education institution policy - again I don't think we directly concerned about that. Maybe there is license violation but it is somewhat hard to detect when question asked - and again removal of content solves that (and would be done on institution request anyway).

The only case I'd be willing to block deletion is if someone with more than 1mil reputation answers such question... but I hope we already have "questions with John Skeet answer can't be deleted" block. (Ok, maybe questions with answers by 500K+ users should be blocked from deletion). Even then clear guidance on recovering such deleted answers may be better option.

Comment: So newer users can't write a high quality answer but a higher rep one can? I am not sure we should go down the rabbit hole of basing deletion on the reputation of the person who answered the question.

Comment: The fact that not even a single one of these questions has gotten even a single upvote is indeed indicative that they're not actually good questions.  The authors did us a favor when they deleted them.  The only reason I can see for why they were undeleted is to try to help their schools catch them at cheating, rather than because the content is actually useful to the site.

Comment: @JoeW Sounds fair. I've never seen a post from John Skeet that is of low quality... unlike pretty much anyone else (obviously including me). So that's my only real exception case. I'm sort of fine with case even if they content removed... Maybe we need "likely good answer removed" review queue were deleted answers with a lot of votes or lot of total reputation (author + editors) go...

Comment: Should delete based on the quality of the question regardless of any answers on them.

Comment: @JoeW Er no. If there's a 1.3k+ score answer on a question, that question should absolutely not be deleted. "[...] regardless of any answers on them." is untenable.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier what do you mean by a 1.3k score answer? Either way if a question sticks around long enough for it to get a highly upvoted answer chances are it is not a low quality question in need of deletion.

Comment: @JoeW I mean one thousand and 300 hundred upvotes. If a question had an answer, that have a score of 1,300, it should absolutely influence the question's deletion, or rather, not deletion.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier My question is how would a low quality question last long enough to attract an answer that gets 1300 votes? If a question lasts that long then why would it get deleted for quality reasons?

Comment: @JoeW do you think following questions (complete text): "How can an int be cast to an enum in C#?" is high quality? I'd bet it would get -10 pretty quickly... yet it has 4K+ up-votes on [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29485/477420). Just an example of question being useful while not really being example of high quality well researched one.

Comment: Well I know 500K+ rep users (not a lot but there are) which answer bad questions/duplicates, just to get more rep. Sad but true. And if you reduce the threshold to, say, 50k, then you have a _lot_ of those... Bad idea.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre note that your comment is to some other statement - I only said "no low quality answers" without judging questions... If question turned out to be duplicate one can move *visible* high quality answer to duplicate or edit question to no longer be duplicate, this is way harder if question is deleted. (I'm really doubt that 500K+ users post answers for rep... but that's separate unrelated question)