# People are removing their questions instead of accepting an answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I've helped some beginners and new members on SO today and multiple times, my answer helped them (as I got a "thank you" comment) but when I went to check the page, they had removed the entire question. I believe this happened at least three times to me today, maybe more.

It's not even about the magic internet points I would get from an accepted answer. It's fairly common to see beginners just miss the concept of accepting an answer, so if I only get an upvote or *even* just a 'thank you' comment, I at least know I helped them.

But deleting the entire question seems counterproductive and not the point of this website.

Can we prevent new users from doing this?

I can certainly understand *why* users are doing this; they probably feel ashamed for missing something obvious, or simply don't see the point on keeping such a question around as they have got their answer and want to move on.

Comment: *Can we prevent new users from doing this?* --> we already prevent question deletion if the answers have upvotes.

Comment: Adding on to what @TemaniAfif said, without an upvote there's no way for the system to know that your answer is helpful content (unless the devs wrote a parser for comments that said "Thank you", which would never happen and still doesn't indicate anything more than politely recognizing that someone *tried*). I don't think we would want askers to be stuck unable to delete their questions just because someone answered them, even if they didn't find the answer helpful.

Comment: Good points, thanks. But since between posting an answer and deleting the question there may only be a few minutes, how can anyone that is not OP reasonably upvote a good answer? Perhaps deleting a question with an answer should be permitted only after the answer has a certain age, giving it a chance to get an upvote from someone else than OP, assuming that OP isn't going to do that anyway. Then the message that prevents them from deleting the question might tell them that it is better to upvote and accept good answers instead.

Comment: *they probably feel ashamed for missing something obvious* --> if it's really something obvious, I would agree with the deletion in this case. By the way, are you able to provide some links? I know you cannot see deleted posts but you probably kept the link in history

Comment: You missed the possibility that the school/college/university term has just started in some places and they're getting help and deleting their questions before they are caught out

Comment: Kind of agree with @TemaniAfif about the question not being worthy of being around. Are you sure those questions shouldn't just be closed? I often see people answer clearly off-topic questions like typos and similar. Providing links would be helpful to understand.

Comment: I'm confused... none of your recent answers have been deleted... are you actually writing answers or are they comments? The newest deleted answer you have is from 2013.

Comment: @Catija [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57903966/5211833) is a more recent example. Today I answered and OP self-deleted instead of leaving any kind of feedback on the answer (except from moving fenceposts on the requirements in the question).

Comment: @Adriaan I absolutely agree that it is a concern that people have. I’ve seen requests on MSE asking for something like a “can not be deleted within an hour of being answered” sort of thing. But the question makes it seem exceedingly common by saying it’s happened to a single person multiple times per day. I don’t see evidence of that so I’m trying to get a clearer understanding of this specific situation. If we changed something about deleting recently answered questions, it wouldn’t solve this person’s problem.

Comment: @PatelRomil It's unclear because of the mod message in the comments above saying you don't have any recently deleted answers, so we don't really understand what you're talking about here.

Comment: Robert, my bad I missed the mod comment

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't see my answers. I'm fairly sure that some of the answers I have typed up yesterday were removed. Can you check these two urls for example @Catija? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896914/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893184/

Comment: @JochemKuijpers Those are comments, not answers.

Comment: Oh really.. I can't see them myself (which is probably why this got me confused then..). I was sure I answered something that got removed.

Comment: Yep. If you'd written answers (in the last 60 days) and those answers had been deleted, you'd be able to see them here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/1806348 You can find the link to that at the bottom of this page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806348/jochem-kuijpers?tab=answers&sort=newest ... it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1F6z.png

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions