# What if we migrated "do my homework" questions to Code Golf?

Tags: discussion, migration, homework

This might be slightly facetious on my part, but wouldn't it be fun to start migrating "do my homework" questions to Code Golf?

Not for any benefit towards the asker, of course.  I just think it might be amusing to see what would come out of it.

Comment: It will be so much for for Code Golf, right? Oh, wait, no it wouldn't be, as they would likely be off topic there.

Comment: Migrate to /dev/null

Comment: Dunno, @MartinJames - perhaps we should have them printed and mailed to Joe, I'm sure he'd find that *hilarious*.

Comment: How-to questions are not inherently off-topic by any means so I see nothing "fun" about  migrating on-topic questions to somewhere that they would be off-topic.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm fairly sure that OP is referring to 'Do ALL my homework for me while go down to the bar' no-effort, no-research,  deadbeat-questions, not homework in general.

Comment: Anyway, I agree that exporting trash is not a useful activity.

Comment: @MartinJames I see nothing specifying that in the question here, let alone the fact that it has been a long time since I have actually seen a question that asked for Stack Overflow to do their homework assignment for them. Most questions I see like that are actually on-topic questions that may or may not be Too Broad depending on the scope of the question. This still doesn't change the fact that such questions are not inherently off-topic, and that such questions would in-fact be inherently off-topic on the target site regardless of whether or not the question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: _(and I'm fairly certain that the last question I saw that explicitly asked for Stack Overflow to do their homework for them was a joke of some kind)_

Comment: To clarify, I actually am talking about those which are clearly zero-effort homework dumps.  They almost never say "do my homework" verbatim, but they might as well do.  I'm not talking about on-topic homework questions at all.

Comment: Questions don't require resolution effort by the asker. They require research effort (on Stack Overflow) which can be resolved by closing such questions as duplicates if a duplicate can be found, otherwise it is not lacking in research effort. If it is too brad, it's too broad. There is absolutely no need to make derogatory statements about "homework" questions (which are really just how-to questions for the most part) or the users who may post them.

Comment: @TinyGiant the OP here has not proposed making derogatory statements about "homework" questions, (well, not on SO main, anyway).

Comment: @MartinJames this whole question is a derogatory statement against homework questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant You seem to be misinterpreting something here.  I have no problems with homework questions where the asker has actually made an effort.  I'm talking specifically about questions that are literally copying and pasting the assignment specifications.

Comment: **Problem solving effort is irrelevant**. The fact that it is copy and paste of a homework assignment **does not make it off-topic**. The fact that a question is too broad makes the question too broad. The fact that a question is unclear makes the question unclear. The fact that a question is primarily opinion makes makes the question primarily opinion based. The fact that a question is a homework question **is completely irrelevant**.

Comment: CodeGolf has its quite strict requirements, and these questions mainly don't pass it. Most of such questions are VLQ also on there. But I think you are right that offtopic closed questions *should have* a site where they could be migrated, and that the SE does a *very bad* work by simply closing/deleting them.

Comment: @peterh we tried that with Not Programming Related (now Prog.SE), it didnt turn out well, and took a lot of work to backtrack and turn it into a worthwhile site. Ask shog, he'll point you at the history behind all of that, I dont have the links on hand right now.

Comment: The Code Golf moderators would come after us with pitchforks, just like the Programmers moderators did.

Comment: @TinyGiant There were various clashes from the more massive migrations, for example also with the SU. It is acceptable that questions being VLQ *everywhere* shouldn't be migrated to *anywhere*. But there is a lot of questions who could be answerable somewhere, there are also questions who simply fall into a topic which doesn't pass any sites until now. A single event as a single (anyways, particularly hostile) site became hysterical because they *didn't want new content*, is not a reason to practically forbid the question migrations in general, SE-wide.

Comment: If you think it would be amusing to have "do my homework" questions on Code Golf, you can create an account there and ask some yourself. But I doubt you will find it as amusing when you get question banned there. More seriously, I don't understand why you think that migrating crap would be amusing.

Comment: @DonaldDuck guess OP didn't bother to check [requirements for CG questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in their help center, "An objective primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win..." etc

Comment: Does the fact that this has four reopen votes mean that people hate CG?

Comment: Bit late. What if there was a new sight. **"DO MY HOMEWORK.com"**

Answer (score 24):

I don't find this amusing at all.  Migrating questions for the fun of it is ***not*** what migration is for.

There's no benefit to migrating crap questions over anywhere on the network, and homework questions would be no different.  Remember that [a homework question isn't necessarily bad to have here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308252/1079354), it just has to be on-topic.

Answer (score 16):

You'd probably get tons of complaints from Code Golf members and we'd probably get tons of complaints from Code Golf moderators. I don't know about you, but I don't find that fun at all.

(Obviously this won't be any fun for them either, otherwise they wouldn't complain, but that wasn't what you were asking.)

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if screwing with new users is really the way to go here.

That will just confuse them instead of educating them about the site, and add more crap to CG. I can't see any benefit to doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This answer focuses on the fact that "homework" questions (which is a useless term for a specific subset of "how-to" questions or sometimes debugging style questions) are not inherently off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Now you mention in the comments that you're talking about "zero-effort homework dumps". I'll quote [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/4639281) by [@Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9):

> You're conflating three different forms of "effort":
>
> 1. **Research effort:** has the asker searched for a solution before asking?
> 2. **Definition effort:** has the asker put enough thought into the problem to formulate a clear, specific question?
> 3. **Problem-solving effort:** has the asker done anything to solve the problem himself before asking?
>
> We have a close reason for #1: **Duplicate**.
>
> We have *multiple* close reasons for #2: Unclear, Too Broad and a
>   grab-bag of more specific reasons under Off Topic.
>
> We *do not* have a close reason for #3 though, because:
>
> - **Judging problem-solving effort is *really* subjective.** *Assuming sufficient research and definition effort*, you're left to make a
>     decision as to [whether or not the asker has suffered enough
>     yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort);
>     this quickly turns into a sick [Milgram
>     experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment).
> - **Trying to maximize effort actively subverts the purpose of this site.** We're trying to create a library of *reusable* information
>     here, with the idea that if someone takes the time to define their
>     problem and then search for it *they won't have to ask a question at
>     all!* When it *works*, any answer can go on to benefit many people
>     beyond the person who *asked* the question... But that also means that
>     the majority of folks using a given answer are putting in *zero
>     problem-solving effort* beyond what is needed for #1 and #2.
>
>   You see the problem here? If we disallow all questions that don't
>     require investment *beyond* research, we give up the ability for folks
>     to research their problems *using* Stack Overflow, and end up with a
>     library of questions so specific to their askers as to be worthless to
>     anyone else.
>
> [Effort is useful when it produces
>   *results*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort/210868#210868)
>   - so we moderate those results. If your question is clear enough, specific enough and unique enough to prompt the addition of useful
>   information to our corpus, then it has value; otherwise, it does not.
>   The close reasons strive to reflect this goal.

So you see, we have specific close reasons for questions lacking in specific types of effort, but not for questions lacking problem solving effort.

That said, any how-to question (or any question for that matter) can be unclear, too broad, primarily opinion based, or otherwise closeable.

---

Now about the topicality of such questions on PPCG, I imagine that all such questions would be immediately (or very quickly) closed as off-topic which would push them back here. So this would just be a massive waste of time and energy for everyone involved, the asker would probably be overly confused and would still not know how to improve their question in order to make it acceptable here.

So no, this would not be fun, not at all.

Comment: None of the other answers touched on that?  Thought mine did.

Comment: Eh, I didn't really count the last sentence of your answer because it is more of a side-note than anything, and I think it is the most important point here. Anyways, I've edited to remove the reference to the other answers.