# How should I introduce my students to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, education

How do I onboard my class (20 students) to Stack Overflow? They don't want to ask a question that's been asked already.

Comment: What would "onboarding" mean outside of them creating accounts? Avoiding asking duplicates is just a matter of searching for the question before asking it.

Comment: Onboarding would mean typing something like "Hello World" into the question area, upvoting and answering fellow students' questions.

Comment: One thing you'll want them to avoid is having the appearance of being a voting ring. This means they should not be automatically voting up a question or answer just because a fellow student wrote it.

Comment: I also don't think the idea of a "Hello World" question works on SE sites since you want to avoid not only duplicates but trivially answered questions.

Comment: Tell them their grade in the course will be based on their reputation score. I hear the mods like that.

Comment: They may not want to but I bet they will, it is the first step of any student: to ask what already has

Comment: "grade in the course will be based on their reputation score" - the worst idea ever... Students are just students, many of them are not very good in programming (or any other subject), they are just beginners, so what score will they get? Should they create fake questions or spam existing topics to get any points of reputation?

Comment: @liquide that comment was meant as a joke, hence the ironic "I hear the mods like that."

Comment: @TimPohlmann I hope this was a joke, but I heard that some teachers in some universities are really doing this :(

Comment: "Hey students, this is Mr Overflow but, you can call him Stack."

Comment: *They don't want to ask a question that's been asked already* then teach them how to search before asking. That said, after all these years, there are very few/no questions that you students will most likely have that have not been asked dozens/hundreds of times.

Comment: Easy.  Tell them that if they get any downvotes they fail.

Comment: It seems to me that the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) pages should be sufficient. They are very thorough, especially the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page (including the articles linked at the bottom), and of course the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve page. What more do you want?

Comment: But that's like learning to program by reading a book. I have to get them over the initial hurdle of asking their first question.

Comment: @PhillipSenn - Many great programmers learned how to program in great part by reading books. Make them read. This is school after all, and the posts we are pointing you to are not long. If your students cannot make it through a two page write up then that is a problem that needs to be addressed. Assuming they can read a few pages, make them. The initial hurdle is not in merely asking and getting wracked by the community here, it is **learning how the system works**. At the very least you yourself should be aware of these resources if you are not already.

Comment: @PhillipSenn they need to be asking *you* questions, not Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a tutor and it has many rules of conduct that directly contradict with how one should treat a student. Here is a nice read about [homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), for example. Should give an idea why you will always want to be involved in the process of a student asking a question on SO. If a question only slightly differs from what is stated there, the result is likely downvoting / close voting; maybe also some comments.

Comment: No need to introduce. They will come here, learn by self or through SO users and introduce many things back to you ;) It has enough rules already to help them retry again and again. They will love it once they get into the flow.

Comment: There is a formal introduction: *[Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange site lessons (Pluralsight/Kate Gregory)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oie8D4vCbAE&list=PLTbIqtg8Gb0pdq7RBIxAdtw7HGb1jimPg&index=1)*

Comment: @self: That video content has now been removed (the account was deleted). More cumbersome, [use the 10 day trial to see it](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites).

Answer (score 119):

Well, first off, give them a gold star or something for not wanting to ask questions that've already been asked. That's admirable; asking duplicate questions wastes their time *and* ours.

**Then teach them how to search.** I'm serious: pretty much any information a student might possibly want is available somewhere on the 'Net these days, but *finding* it when you don't have the experience and vocabulary to search properly is... Tough. Walk 'em through breaking down a problem, searching for the names for individual concepts, trying different phrasings and keywords, [learning about site-specific search operators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)...

Then walk 'em through [the basics of how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [how to break a problem down into a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - both as a thought exercise and as a way of communicating effectively with others. [Show 'em Jon Skeet's epic guide for asking questions](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and ask 'em to read it.

Now they have some basic tools. Encourage them to use them! Good research can mean asking the right questions... Or just knowing the right questions and then finding existing answers.

Best of luck to them all...

#### See also: [Stack Overflow as a class assignment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115922/stack-overflow-as-a-class-assignment/115934#115934)

Comment: I was with you up until "walk 'em through the basics of how to ask". I can hardly imagine anything beginners (if that's what they are) should be asking. You left out an entire paragraph of your question which is about teaching them how to solve (debug) their own problems. The best advice here is to tell the students that if they are tempted to post a question, they should stop and first try harder to solve it themselves, then ask other students and the teacher (isn't that what they are there for?) in that order, and post only as an absolute last resort.

Comment: I would hope there's more to this class than just asking on SO, @torazaburo. That said, there is considerable overlap here: breaking down a problem in preparation for research is also a good first step for debugging, and the two can dovetail in other ways as well. Have a look at Jon Skeet's guide, linked to above...

Comment: These are good points to consider, but not really addressing what I'm after. Just like I have my students type "<h1>Hello World</h1>", I want them to ask a Hello World on Stack Overflow. And it doesn't have to be answered by you either. I would be happy if only their fellow students saw it.

Comment: Then... Have 'em write up their questions but then just pass them around to classmates for response / feedback, @Phillip.

Comment: @Shog9 As a student, I know that I certainly learned a ton about approaching problems and debugging by trying to formulate a decent question on SO. 19/20 times, I don't end up asking it, but only because my problem was solved by the prior research. I find that an useful skill to have.

Comment: @PhillipSenn: "And it doesn't have to be answered by you either." Sorry, but that's not the way Stack Exchange sites work. It sounds like you want a private version of Stack Overflow, or perhaps a "beginner's corner" where they can practice doing Stack Overflow stuff without being subjected to the full force of the real thing. I guess that could be an interesting & useful feature (and requests for such things come up for time to time on other SE sites, eg Mathematics), but I doubt that we'll see it implemented anytime soon.

Comment: @PhillipSenn - Simply asking students to post a question on Stack Overflow without considering previous questions can go badly. About a week ago, a professor apparently told their class to post a specific homework question on SO as an assignment. Over 30 of them created accounts to keep copying and pasting this assignment in questions, which made folks in the [java] tag mad enough that moderators destroyed all of these accounts and imposed a temporary IP block on addresses from that university. I had a conversation with the faculty about this, but only after the damage had been done.

Comment: @torazaburo teaching a student how to ask the right question doesn't necessarily mean the same thing as teaching them to spam stackoverflow. you can't just "debug harder" and get results, you have to go through the whole process of finding the right question about your problem before you can even hope to solve it. SE's how-to-ask is just generally useful for problem solving.

Comment: As it's an introduction to a non-public SO-like system you appear to be asking for now, @PhillipSenn, have you considered setting up OSQA on a campus server?

Comment: I just want to get the students up and running. I don't want to ask tech services to do anything for me. As a matter of fact, I've got my students going to my own VPS so as not to bother with the campus server.

Answer (score 29):

I think it is a good idea to introduce your students to Stack Overflow. However, make sure to introduce it for what it is: a question and answer site devoted to quality content. More than likely students will take advantage of the existing content (which does have significant coverage) than the ability to ask questions.

Asking a question on Stack Overflow with the goal of breaking the ice similar to writing a "hello world" will go terribly for your students. Do not encourage them to write such questions, as that will not be well-received. Instead, you should reconsider the points raised here by Shog, and have your students actually review the links posted, especially the guide by Jon Skeet.

Why not have an assignment based on your hello world html assignment? I am sure you can come up with something that does not require them to dry test at Stack Overflow while still getting a similar experience. For example: Have every student write a Stack Overflow style question as a single PowerPoint slide, and then go through them on your projector anonymously (to focus on the content). Allow the students to critique the style of the question and perhaps use raising hands as a voting exercise.

Comment: This. Having them get acquainted with Stack Overflow by finding the "Ask a question" button, posting "Hello." and pressing the big blue button at the bottom accomplishes *nothing*. At best, their Not-a-Question will be swiftly deleted by various quality/content filters. At worst (hopefully not, but results may vary), they will be subjected to the full scorn of SO, comments and downvotes and all. Not the very best type of introduction to what potentially could be a helpful tool to master.

Answer (score 29):

If they can use Google, they are already "onboarded" to what is the appropriate use of the site for them, namely to search for information. The right guidance here is to help them with how to craft useful searches, as mentioned in Shog9's excellent answer.

What is their level? Assuming they are beginners, I would not go anywhere near having them think about asking questions, or even sign up. You might want to point them instead to some chat site where people enjoy helping newcomers, if such a thing exists.

However, make sure you are not falling into the trap of teaching them, instead of "OOP", for example, "GOOP" ("Google-based programming"), or worse, "SOOP" (StackOverflow-based programming"), where any time any one can't figure something out, they try to Google it, or ask a question on SO. In 95% (98%?) of cases, problems can be figured out by one or both of "reading the fantastic manual" or "working out the problem yourself".

As regards the "manual", I find all too many cases where people seem to not even know that the manual exists (I work on the JS tag, so that would mainly be MDN). Or if they do, they seem incapable of reading it and digesting it. In no small number of cases, the answer is in the first line or paragraph of the relevant manual page! Point them to the definitive manuals for whatever language/environment you are teaching them.

Equally importantly, teach them how to solve problems themselves. Such skills will be indispensable when they go out into the real world. Teach them basic techniques of problem isolation, such as divide and conquer. Show them how to write simple test cases--in the case of JS, the node REPL or the devtools console are excellent playgrounds. Teach them how to read error messages and think about what they might mean--most error messages are actually quite informative--rather than just throwing their hands up. Teach them how to **reason** about their programs. Teach them the technique of walking through their code in their heads, or on paper, and about [rubber ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Teach them basic debugging tools, such as breakpoints. All of this will go much further in helping them move ahead in the learning process than blindly searching for answers to problems that in many cases they cannot even articulate, or throwing mud at the wall, much less posting "My code doesn't work" questions on SO.

Answer (score 16):

*They don't want to ask a question that's been asked already* then teach them how to search using before asking because the search on the actual site is ineffective at best.

#### With apologies to [Chuck Palahniuk](http://chuckpalahniuk.net/)

> 1. **Teach them how to use a step debugger!** How do kids graduate college and not know how to use a step debugger?
> 2. See #1!
> 3. Teach them how to read language/api/site guidelines documentation for comprehension.
> 4. See #1!
> 5. Make them use their REAL NAMES so you can see what they are asking and the answers they are getting.
> 6. See #1!
> 7. Teach them to always use immutable data structures that will eliminate 49.5% of their errors.
> 8. See #1!
> 9. Teach them to never allow references to be `null` that will eliminate 49.5% of all their errors.
> 10. See #1!
> 11. Teach them to always use a version control system and how to diff versions that way they can see what changed from working to
>     non-working and put it back.
> 12. See #1!
> 13. Teach them to take criticism and that *terse*, *concise* and *curt* comments are not the same thing as *rude*.
> 14. See #1!
> 15. Teach them that an *entitlement attitude* at a place where people help them for free is not going to be welcomed.
> 16. See #1!
> 17. Teach them that professionals are probably helping them and they want future peers to be able to do their own work. Doing their work
>     for them in college just leads to doing their work for them when they
>     become a co-worker, think about how that is going to come across.
> 18. See #1!

If you have not used a step debugger there is no way you have effectively tried to solve the problem(s). At this point if they still have an issue they should be able to effectively communicate what that issue is and what they have tried to do to solve it and what the desired outcome is and be very successful at getting help.

That said, after all these years, there are very few/no questions that you students will most likely have that have not been asked dozens/hundreds of times. So it will be next to impossible to ask a question that is not a duplicate.

Comment: 7. Read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  8. Teach them how to use Google to search for answers. 9. See #1!  (Actually, I think maybe 8 should be moved up to 2 or 3, with appropriate adjustments.)

Comment: Much as I like a good debugger, there's a critical step #0 here: teach them to read their code. Aloud if need-be, to a rubber duck if must be. If you can't say what it's doing, or supposed to be doing, a debugger isnt going to help much... Nor will you be able to explain it to anyone else.

Comment: Love #7 ❤️ Great answer

Answer (score 6):

It might be good to do something like look at new questions, search for dupes and flag them. Also edits to improve grammar, and / or comments to ask for clarification etc. Some of this requires that you already have rep, which will be an issue. Of course, answers are also appreciated if the questions are genuinely new.

You could ask them to write questions and submit them to you to be assessed, rather than submit them to the site. Then you could ask them to answer the best ones from their peers. You could perhaps install a local stack overflow like site to do this - see this answer: [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones)

But at this point, most simple questions have been asked and answered already, so think of stack overflow as a mostly read-only site for students, and teach them to search it and find what they want.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of starting by teaching them how to ask a question, why not start by teaching them how to answer one?

I think you can learn a lot more by attempting to research, and find the answer to a question that you don't know "off the bat", than you do by asking a bad question that you haven't really thought through.

Answering a question that you, yourself had to research to find, in my opinion, is very satisfying (as long as it's not a mundane 'how do i declare a string in x' question).

By deconstructing other people's answers, flagging unhelpful or vague questions, and contributing your ideas when you are sure it's worth contribution, i think you will learn a lot more about how this site should work, and how you should put yourself in a position to learn beyond university, rather than learning to ask a simple question that has been asked a million times.

Comment: I like this idea and will probably go in this direction. BUT StackOverflow says not to make trivial changes because they will get put into a queue.

Comment: @PhillipSenn you don't need to get them to make trivial edits. Understand what a bad question is first and then you know how to avoid asking them - asking a good question that has not been asked before should be a rare occurrence. If you have read a range of questions and answers by the time you first need to truly ask one, you should have a good base to go from.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to introduce them to StackOverflow is to teach them how to ask good questions.

I find the "Ask a new question form" invaluable most of the times without neither have to press "Submit".
When you write a good question, most of the time you will automatically find the answer.

Comment: The problem is that this is easier said than done. Fundamentally, asking good questions requires the ability to **think**, which you cannot provide guidelines or a checklist for.

Comment: I think there are already good guidelines to ask good questions. By the way a downvote seems excessive,

Comment: Not my DV. Anyway, DV's on Meta just mean "I disagree". WRT guidelines, the problem is that **following** the guidelines requires, first, **reading** them, then **thinking** about them, the ability to do either of which can not always be taken for granted.