# Can we sticky an Open Letter to Students?

Tags: discussion, homework

Can we please sticky/feature a post similar to *[Programmers'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)* [Open Letter to Students](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) post in the side bar like it was a few weeks ago (probably because it was 'hot')?

[Several<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989839/c-how-to-use-pointer-variables-within-my-program) [homework<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989811/war-game-with-numbers) [questions<sup>3</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989846/tuition-calculator-produced-goose-eggs) from new accounts have arisen in the last <strike>few hours</strike> 30 minutes that are undoubtedly the product of the fresh school year, and I'd bet money there are many more to come.

It'd be a great reminder for those that are just signing up to re-consider asking a question that might already have an answer, and a great refresher on proper Google-fu and self-sufficiency, two pretty important skills for our budding future colleagues.

I understand we can just downvote/close/dupe-hammer these questions, but as has been discussed many times before we'd likely be shutting out several potentially good, rule-abiding bright eyed future engineers and avid users of the site by impressing upon them that they are unwelcome here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I guess \[ask] and [mcve] are enough if they read those two links carefully.

Comment: @Tushar You are correct, though if I were a student unaware of the world of StackExchange and needed an answer _right now_ about some homework that had an effect on my grades and my future and career, I might think "I know how to ask a question just fine" and churn out one of the three linked questions above.

Comment: Open Letter won't help either. Chances are they(_students_) won't even see that in the sidebar OR _I'm here to get my homework done, I don't want to read some letter_.

Comment: @Tushar It garnered 600+ upvotes on P.SE. Seems like it worked well over there.

Comment: Votes are just to show the usefullness of the post. It doesn't mean it's working there(I hope it should work). If you see, the students posts will be flooded here on main SO site and not on P.SE. And regarding sticky post, that link can be posted in comments.

Comment: @Tushar I understand what meta votes are for. I'm simply saying it's an opportune time to get new student users to actually _read_ the How To Ask rules.

Comment: I doubt that posters of bad/lazy homework questions will check the sidebar for this. Some *might* read it if you post it as a comment, but most probably won't, and those that do read it will probably shrug it of. I add it in comments anyway because it's little effort and even a *small* chance of teaching the poster anything is probably worth it, but I have no illusions about its effectiveness.

Comment: @Qix That it got 600+ upvotes means that tons of active answerers *want* people asking these kinds of questions to actually read a post like that.  It doesn't mean that they actually are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my experience, there isn't really a seasonality to when students ask bad questions. This is a global site, and schools are in session around the year. Bad homework questions still keep getting asked in North American summer months, for example. There is a seasonality to when students urgently flag their questions for deletion, hoping to hide their cheating from professors at the end of a term, but that's a different matter.

The best way I've found to combat bad homework questions is to engage professors directly, such as was done [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254433/should-i-send-students-to-stack-overflow) or [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335386/how-should-i-introduce-my-students-to-stack-overflow). There have been a number of cases where students pasted their homework on the site with the class number and instructor contact information within it. In one case, they even accidentally posted the school's anti-cheating policy with the question.

Moderators have used these as points of contact with teachers, and many classes now dedicate a bit of their introductory sessions to how not to interact with Stack Overflow, sometimes with screenshots of these cheating attempts. We've found that teachers have been extremely receptive to polite contacts from us about their students, and I've seen this to have a long-lasting impact on what we get from those classes.

Unfortunately, the kind of students who would take cell phone photos of their exam and post them from inside the hall (which has happened multiple times) aren't going to pay any attention to a link on the side of the screen. Such a pinned post would turn into a fun bikeshed argument for the Meta crowd, as these highlighted posts often do, but I don't think it'd accomplish much. I prefer to target the source, the authorities that students might actually listen to.

How best to do this is something I don't have an answer for, but I know Tim Post and others were working on more university outreach.

Comment: *"In one case, they even accidentally posted the school's anti-cheating policy with the question."* And this is why a sticky post in the sidebar wouldn't work. The people who need to read it don't even read their own questions!

Answer (score 7):

It's a wave, not an epidemic.  Deal with the problematic questions that get asked as they come up - if they're not at the quality that we want questions to be, then they should be handled in that manner.

Ultimately this doesn't apply to *just* homework questions, which aren't off-topic by themselves here; this applies to **all** questions that you see on the site.  Are they poorly researched?  Downvote it.  Are they a duplicate?  Close as a dupe.  Are they unclear?  Close as unclear.  The list goes on.  No reason to put a banner somewhere which will more than likely get ignored.