# Using Stack Overflow to teach students to debug programs

Tags: discussion, education

I am teaching a class on *program debugging* in Python and Java to students who range from beginner to intermediate developers. The goal of the class is basically to teach students to take someone else's buggy code, find the bug and suggest a fix. Most of my students already use SO as a resource, although they would maybe gain from being formally introduced to the tool.

It was already discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335386/how-should-i-introduce-my-students-to-stack-overflow) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254433/should-i-send-students-to-stack-overflow) how to introduce students to asking questions on Stack Overflow. I am interested in **how to introduce them to *answer* questions.**

I remember that one of the giant leaps I took as a developer happened when I started giving a shot at answering questions on SO. For that reason I am interested in encouraging students to do the same, either for marks or as a bonus to the class.

SO is such an important tool for developers nowadays that I believe it should take a place in the classrooms, but I want to start a discussion on how that should be done.

Among other things:

1. Has this been done already?
2. How can I promote students' answers on Stack Overflow without
   affecting the quality of the site?
3. In the case I want to incorporate SO in some graded assignment,
   how could it be done in a sound way?

**Edit**: After reading all answers, I feel the relevant issues are that...

1. Finding good questions is hard in itself and it is not a process I
   need nor want my students to go through
2. There is no value added to having my students post on SO if I am able to mimic the process in a controlled environment.
3. Tracking students answers will be tedious, especially since they can be edited by other users for improvements.

For the above reasons, I found the suggestion of finding good unanswered question myself and submitting them as assignment particularly interesting. It has the advantage of allowing for a controlled environment without losing any of the pedagogical value.

I will post my experience here after this class is over.

Comment: An issue is that a significant portion of new questions one encounters are unclear or somehow unanswerable - you might have to teach them to wade through those, but even then, once they find something, there's a good chance that an answer (or a few) will be posted by the regulars here very shortly, likely before an inexperienced coder has had the chance to. Maybe consider having them look at good, solid, *old* questions (not to answer, since one has almost certainly already been posted, but to debug)? Answering newer questions before the answer is revealed by another requires skill and timing.

Comment: Of course, it's OK if two people independently post the same or similar answers within a reasonable period of time, @Certain. Being the fastest gun in the west is not required, especially if you can *explain* the solution better than the speed demon can spit out code.

Comment: I like the idea of taking old quality questions out of SO and use them to devise assignments which would mimic SO without being directly on site. This has the advantage of not sending 120 unexperimented users question-hunting in the same timezone, under the same tag. Furthermore, SO can sometimes be unforgiving so creating a controlled environment which looks like SO sounds like an idea worth exploring.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I don't know what tag(s) are you planning to use, but in the tag I'm active in there are plenty of old questions without answer, and I'm not talking about bad questions, I'm talking about questions with several upvotes. Maybe you can start there, something like *"hey kids, you have to choose questions older than 1 month, with no answer and with at least 1 upvote"*.

Comment: Encouraging students to recognize questions that are already answered would be a useful tool as well for the students to learn, as it helps the student to recognize the importance of searching for an answer first.  You could have students send you a screenshot of duplicate flags they cast marked helpful if that's something you want to encourage.

Comment: One possibility is that you could use a [Stack Overflow Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). That would allow them to use the same UI, but you could cherry-pick the questions (i.e. copy picked questions over from SO, with attribution, of course). The drawback to using SO, or a Team, is that all the students get to see what other students post and/or what other SO members post. That could make grading a challange.

Comment: "Most of my students already use SO" Well, I hope they're not banned from answering questions currently, since that would be a problem :P

Comment: You should teach them how to look up documentation, how to read it (its like a legal contract), then a bold idea, READ THE ERROR MESSAGE.

Comment: And knowing how to use WinDbg is also important. See my intro https://pastebin.com/Qdf5C2Lt

Comment: When I was in uni, my class got an assignment to write up mini essays on particular software topics. The lecturer then said *"if you are interested in receiving feedback from industry experts you could potentially post your completed article to this mailing list but it's not a requirement"*. Well. The result was that mailing list being flooded by about 500 students who thought that posting to the list would earn them more marks. So be careful about sending a huge influx of students into the 'real world' at the same time, it can have unexpected consequences. A private SO team might work though!

Comment: @Robotnik: A mailing list is fundamentally different: the assumption is that all subscribers read (or at least skim) *all* messages, so a flood of newbies is a disasters.  But Stack Overflow's popular tags are already at firehose volume and mostly full of crap already.  Bumping a lot of old questions with answers that range from good-ish to mediocre or bad is not going to be a big deal, especially in popular tags.  Especially if they're not all in the same language tag.  It might create some extra load on the new-user review queue, but compared to the global volume that's probably small.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: If you end up trying this, please post an answer to document your experience.

Comment: There are not enough new good quality question for 120 students to answer- the vast majority of questions they answer will likely be questions that should be closed, mostly duplicates

Comment: IMHO beginner to intermediate programmers trying to answer debug questions on SO isn't a recipe for great quality. It might be a great learning experience for the students, but it doesn't align with the goals of SO.

Comment: @Noodles This may be different for OP since he's using Python (I'm not really familiar with Python) but "reading error messages" is often completely useless in some languages.

Comment: Not an answer, but kudos for teaching debugging to students. It's a very specific skill set that I wish more developers had, the number of questions on Stack Overflow that wouldn't exist if those people knew how to debug is probably massive.

Comment: For a formal introduction to the tool, see *["Using Stack Overflow and Other Stack Exchange sites"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oie8D4vCbAE&list=PLDBBFaqYTcl_4_AqIFmn9J8uICwMMdiP8&index=70)* (though weirdly the playlist is in reverse order, and you will need to manually open the previous item after one item ends (or make your own playlist)).

Comment: @TylerH FYI error messages in Python ***are*** helpful, they include a reason, type and traceback.

Comment: I think you can still take the questions and let the students debug the code without them actually posting the answer on SO.

Comment: The replies to this question (both comments and answers) goes a long way to illustrate why a lot of people think of SO as hostile/toxic. What on earth is up with people saying students shouldn't attempt to answer questions.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen While I agree with the general sentiment, I think the answers that actually suggest strategies for interacting with Stack Overflow are broadly okay. If you are going to introduce students to Stack Overflow through coursework, you need do it in a carefully managed way, for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: OK, for the formal introduction to the tool (Stack Overflow) mentioned in a previous comment, I have now made a playlist that has the 70 small modules ***in the correct order***: *[Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange site lessons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oie8D4vCbAE&list=PLTbIqtg8Gb0pdq7RBIxAdtw7HGb1jimPg&index=1)*. (You can just leave comments on it if you want to have something changed for this new playlist.)

Comment: @TylerH Python apparently uses some error scheme from Unix. So Windows' errors are recoded into Unix errors. So Python people should become familiar with the Linux error system even when on Windows. But  how many time have I seen a question *My program says Access Denied, any idea what might cause this* or *My program says File Doesn't Exist - what could cause this*.

Comment: I also make a new point. On Stackoverflow *physic debugging* is done, not structured. That is because most questions don't have enough information. The VBA tag is almost entirely about Excel spreadsheets. Only code is posted not data. You can't run it, lines like `.cells(4, -3).something` are meaningless. **Perhaps choosing questions that are good debugging questions out of the database** and resolving those.

Comment: And as a fun fact VBScript/VBA/VB.NET all use the same error numbers developed by Bill Gates decades ago. His programming work lives to this day.

Comment: Hi, I'm not a teacher, but I used Stackoverflow as a teaching medium for  student in Car repair/paint, Electricity, Seller/manager, and Wood worker. I worked for 4 years in a "Centre de formation professionnelle". 
None of them where ban for asking even with their small education level and their issue with the english language.
Before using SO, question had to be build and review by their group.
Once they understood the "game" they were more "snaky" and "unwelcoming" that SO member.
From 1 question per day per student, the review proccess reduce it to 4 per month.

Comment: You might consider asking about this over on the [CS Educators Stack Exchange](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What does "answering a question on SO" as a proficiency goal really mean to you? To explain to someone where they went wrong & what is right & what is right-thinking & good application of the relevant correct- notions? This teaching that is ideal & would ideally happen to a colleague & grows & demonstrates problem solving & articulate explanation is not necessarily what gets upvoted on SO & not necessarily what you want to be learned. What *do* you want to be learned? Indeed what pursuant to what goal here are you *teaching*?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** *Not a teacher here, just happen to know some of them in my family*

---

Seeing that you have 120 students, it might be a bad idea to unleash them all into the jungle called SO at once. You probably can't keep up with the things they run into. Making them aware of SO and site policy is a noble cause, I think. Especially teaching them to write good quality answers. We tend to lack the good quality on a good number of occasions.

As others already noticed, it might be hard to find good quality questions they can answer, so I suggest you do that for them. Perhaps you can find about 5 of them and hand them out as assignment or test.

The assignment would probably be the best way to go as compared to a test, where usually you're not allowed to use your computer and/or cellphone, since that comes closest to the "natural way" of answering questions.

When it comes to grading, I suggest you let students hand in their assignments to you directly rather than posting them on SO. Besides getting 120 answers on maybe 5 questions causing a large "meta-like" effect, it might be impossible for you to grade them all before the poorly scoring ones are downvoted into oblivion. You might even want to consider students that hold a grudge against one of their peers that might vote on the answerer instead of on the quality of the answer.

To introduce some feedback into the class you could, perhaps in study groups seeing you have 120 students, discuss the answers that were handed in and see if the group could come up with the combined "best" answer. To show them how SO works, and what happens with answers you could post these as Community Wiki. In that way you don't take credit for your students work, but their answer gets the scrutiny of the SO community.

How about you find a few old, unanswered and positively scored questions and give them as handouts, on this old magical thing, made from trees, called paper. Then let them write, with a pen or pencil, an answer. Then you could grade these. To insert a feedback mechanism you can, in groups perhaps seeing you have 120 students, discuss their answers and come up with an combined effort best answer. Which you could then post as CW as to not give anyone internet reputation for work that isn't theirs.

Comment: Another thought - if OP isn't having their students interact with the questions on Stack Overflow directly, then they don't necessarily even need to be unanswered questions. They could pick a selection of old, well-answered questions at an appropriate skill level, strip away the answers, and provide them to the students in an off-site format, to answer for grading.

Comment: *students that hold a grudge against one of their peers* Or, y'know, have friends.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl true, but I guess the "be more welcoming" thing is still in the back of my mind.

Comment: I'm imagining a flood of low-effort "answers", from students who are just trying to do what the instructor told them to do. From where they sit, "the authority figure told me to go to the assignment site and type my best answer in the box, and I'm sorry it's not very good, but **that was the assignment**, so how can you tell me I'm not supposed to do my assignment? Do you seriously think you outrank my teacher, Mr. Internet Scold?" It's very good advice to keep their answers in the classroom, where they belong.

Comment: The drawback of using questions that are answered already is that students are smart and will search for the questions. Depending on how you want to grade your students' work, the students seeing the existing answers might be a problem.

Comment: @cecilya, that is indeed something to keep in mind. Perhaps it is best to find questions that are unanswered.

Comment: @Luuklag:  If they are unanswered, then usually with good cause.  Unanswerable or just effin **hard** problems.

Answer (score 38):

How about you get a Stack Overflow for teams account? Maybe Stack Overflow could give a good student discount for education purposes instead of the usual price tag. You'd have to contact their sales for a discount of course. That is of course up to Stack Overflow if they want that or not.

That way you can teach them the basics without unleashing them in the wild, correct their asking and answering style, and also make it insightful to the rest of the students what has happened to a post.

Then when they "graduate" you could give them assignments to answer questions on the real Stack Overflow, where they write reports on how they had to research the subject, how they came to answers and how it was received etc...

Comment: That's the best scenario this situation fit in perfectly, assume the school is a big organization who just needs answers for their employees.

Comment: @window.document But they don't... they want to answer questions.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl then would large SO team members consider answers from students?

Comment: @window.document Not sure exactly what you mean, but if it's about how teams works I have no idea.

Comment: I would think the students learn how to phrase their questions on there, and other students can answer it. It also will fire some competitiveness among the scholers for more points, giving better answers, etc.. all in a curated environment where the teacher can oversee it and guide it. That way they learn and prepare for Stack Overflow "real world, hard as nails"

Comment: I don't think a "Stack Overflow on rails" is needed for students. Every single one of us was an equally new user once. We welcome them here. So why put students into a walled garden and give them a fake, padded version? SO is deliberately designed to be usable by normal humans, without needing training wheels.

Comment: @DewiMorgan https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project aparently not...

Comment: That's really cool, @Tchallacka - I like that admins are thinking of ways to make SO more approachable. But my point was: I don't see any advantage to giving students a sandbox, other than to protect *us* from *them*, which should be unnecessary as unlike every other answerer here, including you and me, they're actually *getting training* on how to answer well. Their answers should average better quality than most, not worse, so why hide them, when they would otherwise help the community?

Comment: @DewiMorgan Stack Overflow community can be a really harsh mistress for some starters. Answering questions that have answers already by a relatively inexperienced person, will most likely lead to downvotes. Students answering on eachothers questions or upvoting them(that will happen) will lead to bans/voting ring suspicions etc... I would first sandbox em, get them in the flow in a controlled enviroment without community swooping in, down/close voting, or answering before others have a chance. I would "set them free" after training.

Comment: So, "Protect us from them, but *claim* we're protecting them from us being assholes to them because we didn't protect ourselves from them." I see your point, but I disagree with it: these will be infinitely better answers than any from a student who just found SO by Googling, so should be on live. Travis J suggests ways to combat any possibility of low quality slipping through, but honestly, I think it's an overblown fear: these answers will be above average from the get-go.

Answer (score 35):

> Has this been done already?

This type of stuff happens all the time. It is just generally done without any sort of consultation or consideration of outcome so the people here that curate the site end up with a very bitter reaction to the idea of students running amok.

That doesn't mean it can't be done properly though.

> How can I promote students' answers on Stack Overflow without affecting the quality of the site?

You can't, really. This would essentially fall into the realm of voting directly on a user which is generally discouraged here. Stack Overflow is based on voting on content as it is naturally encountered.

*Please do not individually "promote" answers based solely on the fact that a student posted them.*

> In the case I want to incorporate SO in some graded assignment, how could it be done in a sound way?

What you could do, though, is create a two session lab for this.

The first session would be to write an answer, the second would be to post it.

Stack Overflow saves a draft of your last written post prior to submission. You can take advantage of this fact.

**In lab...**

- Session 1: Have your students find a question they wish to answer; NOT the same question, one student per question. Then, have them write the answer to the question into the answer box and see how it looks with the WYSIWYG editor. DO NOT submit. Copy a link to the question to a text editor, and then copy the entire answer to the text editor; have them turn in the print out of that and review and grade them.
- Session 2: Upon grading the assignments, along with a grade give an indication of whether or not the answer may be posted. During lab, while present, allow the students who were approved to *optionally* post their answers if they want to depending on the current state of the question. There will have been a delay due to grading. This will be beneficial, as it will allow the students to also compare what they came up with versus what the community here did; this will teach them about creating content which stands the test of time as some of what they found will probably have ended up being closed as not meeting standards, or answered in a manner which they did not foresee.

This approach would prevent and solve many of the issues that users here are concerned with while at the same time allowing you to not only see the individual contribution of your students but also allowing them once complete to have a legitimate answer posted to the site. It is a win win scenario.

Comment: This really is a win-win scenario. I would have loved it if a teacher in College had given us assignments like this; these aren't the kinds of things you study for an exam and forget later, but they aren't the kind of things people tend to just pick up as they go either. Learning how to correctly work through questions and answers like this with guidance can turn people's first experiences with Stack Overflow into a very positive experience rather than the daunting experience it is for some newcomers.

Comment: This feels like a good "training wheels for the teacher" idea. It lets the teacher verify that what is being taught is genuinely resulting in good quality answers. In the future, the "don't submit on day 1!" limitation could almost certainly be lifted, once there was confidence that the average student answer was consistently better than the average answer by the public (and if that didn't happen, to either rewrite or stop teaching the class!)

Comment: @DewiMorgan lol, it doesn't seem like a reasonable conclusion to me that the instructor should stop teaching the class if student answers fail to be better than the average SO answer.

Comment: @DewiMorgan although I suppose you could have meant that they should stop teaching that section (posting to SO) rather than they should stop teaching CS 101, or whatever the course is. I still wouldn't agree, but it's a less harsh suggestion :)

Comment: @HFBrowning My point was, in the unlikely event that taking the course caused no improvement over *not* taking the course, the ineffectual course would either need to be reexamined, or scrapped. I'm puzzled why you feel that's not "a reasonable conclusion": what conclusion would you take from that outcome? But that outcome's *very* unlikely anyway: teaching should result in noticeably better-than-average answers. Following this answer's recommendations may well make that obvious enough that the "training wheels" could be removed for future versions of the class.

Comment: Admittedly there are other low-probability reasons for a below-average response, such as "the students were drawn from a pool of incompetents", but I'd imagine such things would come up when reexamining the course.

Comment: @DewiMorgan I suppose you and I have different bars when measuring SO, then. I don't consider the average answer on here to be comparable to someone who hasn't taken a class. In fact, after programming full-time for several years now, I still feel like most of my answers are only average, rather than better than average. I maybe have 2 better than average answers. I wouldn't expect a student to be able to provide a better than average answer unless they're quite clever.

Comment: And to me the opposite of "better than average" is not just "below-average", but rather average to below average.

Comment: @HFBrowning Just mathematically, the answers that remain on SO tend to be "better than average", but that's because bad answers are culled, which raises the average. But I think you're right, and I caused lack of clarity by talking about "average". Rephrasing then: I'd claim most first-answers, even by students, are good and worth posting [a questionable premise?]. So if, when following this answer's advice, most first-answers by these students are found to be so bad they shouldn't be posted, then there's likely a serious problem with the course to be addressed before it could be taught again.

Answer (score 17):

## Use case studies and teach them how to use Stack Overflow effectively

So many of the questions I see on Stack Overflow that have issues are because people don't make an effort to write fully formed, correctly scoped, sufficiently detailed questions. I think you would likely have a pretty negative experience if you unleashed 120 "new" programmers who don't yet have the skills to debug their own programs. Part of the point of Stack Overflow is that you go some way, and then ask for help on a more specific part.

IMO you could integrate Stack Overflow quite well into a course for learning how to debug programs, without having direct interaction with the site. A lot of the issues that come up on Stack Overflow are generally related to learning how to ask better questions in real life.

Here's what I think would be great to help people learn:

- Case studies of good questions, break them down and explain why they are good, etc.
- Similar for bad questions
- Exams using questions where you have hidden the upvote/downvote scores and comments and ask the students to "grade the questions" or suggest how they could be improved
- Ask them to write questions for Stack Overflow, but have them submit them to you for grading and feedback.

Answer (score 10):

IMO:

- **Don't specifically send your students here with the task to answer questions.**  All this will lead to is a minority of your students *maybe* learning something and a uncomfortable rise in the "low quality posts" review queue.
- **Do teach them *how* to write good answers**, but don't do that "live" on the site.  I'd rather suggest using the site (and its many questions and answers) as a resource, e.g. in order to find ...

  - ... *old, good answers*.  They can be used to showcase what makes an answer good (structure, being to the point, coherent language, ...)
  - ... *old, good, unanswered questions*.  You can use them to show that sometimes answers are *really* hard to write / find.  *Maybe* you could even attempt to answer them together with your students (e.g. distribute the research efforts needed, gather results, compile an answer together).
  - ... *"low quality answers"*.  Dissect them and teach how to improve them.

Answer (score 6):

This is somewhat off-topic, but...

Regarding this: "It was already discussed here and here how to introduce students to asking questions on Stack Overflow." - I'd like to suggest that the main goal of a teacher who deals with beginners and intermediate-level students should be to teach them to ***NOT*** ask questions on Stack Overflow.

I assert that any legitimate question a beginner-level student can ask is either already answered on SO, or is much better answered by a teacher. The only kind of question that such a student can pose is either a duplicate or "I don't understand what's taught in class, please help me".

In practical terms, I think you'd be better off teaching strategies on how to SEARCH Stack Overflow and encouraging your students to ask questions from you as their teacher.

Another relevant thing you could teach is using a debugger - many beginners do not know how to do that. Finally, creating an MCVS - not necessarily as a precursor to a Stack Overflow question, but as a tool to reveal the problem in the code - would not go amiss.

Comment: "I assert that any legitimate question a beginner can ask is either already answered on SO, or is much better answered by a teacher." -- As someone who regularly sees beginner questions that are well worth answering here, I can't say I subscribe.

Comment: I agree with the general stance that learning Stack Overflow should start with **learn how to search Stack Overflow** rather than start with trying to ask and answer.

Comment: @duplode Do you mean "beginners" as in "new SO users" or "beginners" as in "people who are just learning to program"?

Comment: @Arkadiy I was primarily thinking of beginners to the matters covered by the tags I frequent, which occasionally includes beginners to programming in general, and routinely includes "intermediate-level students".

Comment: The whole sentiment that every beginner question that could be asked has already been asked is pure nonsense in my opinion. New technologies are appearing every day. As well, old technologies are being updated such that the prior beginner questions are no longer applicable.

Comment: @TinyGiant "every beginner question that could be asked has already been asked" - that's not what I said. Any question that can be legitimately asked by a beginner programmer learning C, Java, Java Scrtipt, Python or even Schema as their first language has already been asked (or should be asked from the teacher). Furthermore, an intermediate student who is learning their SECOND language from that same list while still in college is in similar position. There will be exceptions, but the general case fills SO with 1000 copies of homework assignments every day.

Comment: @TinyGiant One of my most cherished achievements on SO was asking a beginner's question on a language and having Jon Skeet show up in the answers :) But by then I was not a student. If I still had a teacher, I'd much prefer asking a teacher. And the answer was a book recommendation anyway :)

Comment: I completely disagree with your assertment, and I still can't tell the difference between what you said and what I summarized it to. The two sentences have the same meaning, which is categorically false. My previous comment still applies.

Comment: "a beginner question" on brand new technology is much more likely to be asked by someone experienced learning the technology than someone who is not experienced at all. A true beginner is far more likely to ask a true beginner questions that need to be answered in terms of new technology. As an example, a good beginner question from someone learning Java would be "How does the memory manager keep track of Eden objects?" While a true beginner would ask "What is garbage collection?". Even if the second one is possible to answer, it's much better answered by a teacher.

Comment: @TinyGiant Let me try again: a good beginner question on Java: "Is Java passing argument by value or by reference?". A typical question from a beginner: "I am asigning new value to this `int` function argument and I don't see it change. Why?" One question elucidates some aspect of Java. The other can be asked (and has been asked) about C, Python, Java and many others.

Comment: @Arkadiy so what? Now you're differentiating between good beginner questions and bad in vague hand-waving manner. How does that have anything to do with your assertion that all beginner questions that can be asked already have? Are you trying to say that the distinction is that all beginner questions that fall under your umbrella of "good beginner questions" have already been asked? If so, that is still false.

Comment: What I am saying is that a true beginner has so many "bad" questions to ask that asking a good one would be a rare occasion. Someone who is new to a particular technology but not to the programming in general does not have that problem. There will be exceptions, sure, either by chance or by unusual talent.

Comment: That is an entirely different argument. While it may or may not have merit, it has no bearing on your assertion "that any legitimate question a beginner-level student can ask is either already answered on SO, or is much better answered by a teacher", which is what I'm rebutting.

Comment: @TinyGiant no, the argument is a justification for my cited position. "Any" may be an overstatement, but the overwhelming majority is indeed the case. And the teacher should orient the teaching towards the majority, not toward exception.

Comment: I don't understand how the two assertions are in any way related.

Answer (score 4):

Please, don't send your students to this site to try to answer questions.

[What is SO for?](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers

Not for students in general. Students are welcome only if they can act like  professionals or enthusiasts, which sadly in practice means only a small fraction of your students are likely to be welcome. Sending all your students here will cause anguish for almost everyone involved.

SO is not a "debug code for free" site. It is meant to be producing a repository of good programming questions with good answers. Posters of questions are expected to have done debugging themselves, **to the extent** that the problem has been transformed from vague "how do I debug this specific code" (which can help only them) to "why does this API/programming language construct have this unexpected behaviour" (which can help anyone else who is equally puzzled). If a novice at debugging can answer a question, by doing the debugging, the question should never have been asked in the first place because [*vague debugging problems are off topic*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions). If you do this, you will be deliberately sending your students here to answer off topic questions. Please respect this community and don't do that.

Comment: I'm sad that this answer is getting so many downvotes. It's the correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is no longer just for professional and enthusiasts.  It's now for, "[everyone who codes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381430/spurned-authors-deleting-their-questions-after-they-are-closed-as-duplicate#comment679268_381430)", whatever that means.  None of the messaging implies or states that we have quality standards.  Just that if you can or want to program, this is the place.  Say hello to a faster decline of signal to noise.

Comment: Not that I necessarily disagree with this answer, but you're using "professional and enthusiast" as if they were both adjectives of the same programmer. The tour says "professional and enthusiast programmers," which can be expanded to say "professional programmers and enthusiast programmers," meaning two (non independent) groups of people. Sure, students usually aren't professional programmers, but many if not most certainly can be enthusiasts (A person who is highly interested in a particular subject) -- After all, they chose this course of study over dozens of other degrees offered.

Comment: `If a novice at debugging can answer a question, by doing the debugging, the question should never have been asked in the first place because it is off topic` - can you cite a source for this? Aside from questions caused by an outright typo, I'm not aware of any rule that says a well-formed question with an MCVE needs to require a more than specific level of debugging skill to be on-topic.

Comment: _if they can act like professionals and enthusiasts, which sadly in practice means only a small fraction of your students are likely to be welcome._ how do you know about the students? It's not necessary that all of them are not professionals and enthusiasts

Comment: @fbueckert A provocation: if we have quality standards to evaluate posts, why should we care about the personal background of the posters?

Comment: You can read the debate I had with Catija if you want more background, @duplode.  It answers that very handily.

Comment: The part of this answer that I'm much more in agreement with is the whole sentiment  that the students are likely to contribute content without knowing the expectations of Stack Overflow, thus answering questions that should be closed, giving lower quality answers, etc. However, we see that from all kinds of people. People posting link only answers because an API they know does the job without realizing they need to give a full answer. People posting "Me too" answers. People who do whatever for rep farming. These are a worry for *any* large group getting introduced to SO, not just students.

Comment: I am a student and a programming enthusiast, and I can say that sadly only maybe three or four of the 120 students in my year are interested in programming in the slightest, and definitely none are professionals.

Comment: [1/2] @fbueckert I understand your concern about the messaging of the company. However, I feel it is important to make it very clear this messaging should never be about using personal background as criteria for entry. In particular, [the comment by Tim Post you link to in the other discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378753/spooked-by-robotic-repetitive-questions-in-the-first-post-review/378769#comment661548_378769) doesn't do that.

Comment: [2/2] @fbueckert Looking at it from the other side, "professional and enthusiast programmers" is not a decisive factor it comes to the concrete work of content curation. After all, it was the professionals and enthusiasts who asked about boat programming, back in the days when posting rules and guidelines were sufficiently loose.

Comment: @duplode I believe you've entirely misinterpreted my concern.  It's not so much the phrase itself I want, but the good implications that it carries.  Please, read my comments, and the whole argument I had with Catija.  If you did, then I don't think you understand my concern at all.

Comment: @fbueckert I did read it, and I believe I do understand your concern. I'm not attributing to you the view that personal background should be used as criteria. I just think that, in general, invocations of "professional and enthusiast" slide too easily into such a thing, and that that is a problem. Ideally, I would be happy if we stopped worrying about who Stack Overflow is for, and instead have messaging which focuses on *what we want to build here*, and that derives everything else from that end goal.

Comment: @fbueckert I shall continue mercilessly downvoting and voting-to-close posts that have no shred of either professionalism or enthusiasm.

Comment: @duplode For that to happen, we'd have to have *any* artifacts of what we want. Right now, *none* of the messaging mentions quality or standards whatsoever.  We do, however, have lots of messaging about how we're supposed to be inclusive and welcoming, and quit being mean to all the new people!  This is creating a huge experience dichotomy between those new users and curators who have to deal with them.

Comment: @Raedwald Yep.  Downvote quickly, downvote often.  I look at it from a point of investment; if a user invests in their question, I invest in my response.

Comment: @window.document "how do you know about the students": because, being a skilled professional adult, I am able to infer reasonable guesses from clues and context.

Comment: @fbueckert That certainly is a problem. Some course corrections are better than others, though. (There is a Meta [discussion] about this broader issue I have been wanting to post for a year now, but I never seem to get to write it down.)

Comment: @duplode One insight I might be able to add to your discussion: SE wants the users, but doesn't seem to want the additional work required to curate their contributions.  If you write it, I've got some points I can bring up.

Comment: @Raedwald I respect you as an adult, I'm a student and you cannot judge students from past artifacts, clues or context without actually meeting them or questioning them.

Comment: @DanielPryden I downvoted this answer because it doesn't attempt to answer the questions posed by OP. It should have been a comment, IMO. It also makes some wrong claims about the site and who it's for. I suspect the other downvoters did so for the same reason.

Comment: @TylerH [The tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) supports my statement **with its first sentence**.

Comment: @Raedwald Note I said "*some* wrong claims". Specifically, your insinuation that SO is "not for students in general". As window.document already exclaimed, you can't discriminate against students as a class of user. Doing so is, ironically, unprofessional of you. By the by, the tour's third sentence says "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to **every question about programming**" (emphasis mine). A debugging question is a question about programming.

Comment: @TylerH: I am trying to do my best to not get involved in this argument, which is quickly spiraling out of control. But I am surprised by the assertion that this answer doesn't attempt to answer the question. Isn't that the very first sentence of the answer? "Please, don't do this." Now, you are free to downvote it if you think that's a *wrong* answer, but I'm surprised that you think that that's *not an answer at all*.

Comment: @TylerH Only a fraction of "students in general" belong to the set of "professional and enthusiasts". So the statement "Not for students in general" is accurate. And I don't discriminate against students in general. My very next sentence says "Students are welcome only if..."

Comment: Maybe they are not enthusiasts *yet*. Maybe they realize that it is fun to help other people, and that it is fun to code. I once came to this site as a newbie, now I'm studying CS.

Comment: @DanielPryden This post doesn't address any of the questions OP asked. The question is not asking "should I use SO as an education tool in my classroom", it is asking three separate questions about ways to implement SO as an education tool. Implicit in them is the assumption that, yes, SO is going to be used as an educational tool. This post says "no don't do this, because <insert one extreme, cherry picked example of possible outcome> is bad". That's not an answer, it's commentary. You can see literally any of the other answers for examples of posts that *do* answer the question(s) asked.

Comment: @Raedwald Sorry, but that doesn't pass the smell test. *Anyone* is welcome "only if" they prescribe to whatever gate keeping standards we impose for site participation. Singling out students as a group serves no function except... to single out students.

Comment: Maybe I am too weary already, but it seems that almost any new user who had a good introduction on how to use SO would be vastly better than the average new user. I'd rather take *all* students on SO with a *good introduction* rather than *some* that eventually find SO without any guidance.

Comment: @SamHanley If it has an MCVE, then *by the definition of an MCVE* it's already been, as Raedwald puts it, *transformed from "how do I debug this specific code" to "why does this API/programming language construct have this unexpected behaviour"*. (And as a consequence, it's basically useless as an exercise in the act of debugging a broken program.)

Answer (score 4):

**Using the SO question/answer format is great!**

But I suggest not having the students actually post questions or answers.  SO is still a rather unforgiving place to beginners (I lurked for a few years before daring to open an account), and both questions and answers get edited (and sometimes not in the way you want them to be), not to mention that the first comment on a marginal question or answer can sometimes influence other readers to vote a certain way.

I'd write questions like an SO question, expect answers like an SO answer, but I wouldn't use actual questions.  In debugging, the answer is often "obvious" once someone explains it to you, but it is much harder to see otherwise, and if the students can just search on the question, you aren't debugging anymore, you are just reading and regurgitating, not thinking for yourself.

I suggest making up your own questions, and asking them to do one or more of the following:

- provide search strings (within SO or outside, I admit that I still use google, not SO's search engine)
- comment on the question for more information (sometimes very, very important to the debugging process, you have to know where dig for more information)
- answer the question

I think that would be a really cool class.  Thanks for teaching debugging!

Answer (score -8):

imho **Do not do that!**

Apart from Raedwald point i would live to present my experience

I have done it earlier by suggesting my friends whom i taught programming to give answer

and result was very bad they got addicted to reputation points, site privilege etc and that lead to

1. They start finding easy question that they can answer with their limited knowledge
2. Stackoverflow is full of duplicate post and it is easier to find answer online in most of the cases so to earn more rep they Googled problem only to write answer.
3. Their real learning activity become less and less and so they literally wasting time here.

Students should be encouraged to write code that works and gradually improve logis later learn more methodology to write better code ex SOLID

So i strongly suggest you not to  encourage students to write post. Let them figure what is best from them. And given that Stackoverflow is best place for developer they will come here eventually.

bottom line is Stackoverflow is kind of social network for new developers(students ) so if one is not experienced enough he may end up losing more than get profited by it.