# How to handle homework questions that DO violate school policy?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, homework

[This Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823) discusses various SO policies regarding asking and answering homework questions. One of the statements says:

> **Be aware of school policy**. If your school has a policy regarding outside help on homework, make sure you are aware of it before you ask for / receive help on Stack Overflow. If there are specific restrictions (for example, you can receive help, but not full code samples), include them in the question so that those providing assistance can keep you out of trouble.

What should we do when we see questions that we know with 100% certainty are violating school policies? For example, there are a number of questions on Stack Overflow regarding a "binary bomb" problem, e.g.:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786971/binary-bomb-phase-4
- [Binary bomb phase 4 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510684/binary-bomb-phase-4-assembly)
- [Assembly Binary Bomb Phase 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950621/assembly-binary-bomb-phase-4)
- [Binary Bomb - Phase 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640148/binary-bomb-phase-4)

I happen to know the professor who created that homework assignment, and I can guarantee you that all of the above questions are in direct violation of my institution's academic integrity policies (assuming the same lab wasn't given at another institution which I don't believe it is).

What should we do for questions like these that are, on the surface, quality questions, but violate school policies of the author?

Comment: Let the professor know. Like non-disclosure agreements, school policies are none of our (the Stack Overflow community's) business - they're a contract we're not privy to and cannot enforce.

Comment: To follow on Pekka's comment, I've frequently contacted professors when I find homework being dumped on the site in violation of honor codes. This often leads to a professor lecturing their class on this or adding a section about Stack Overflow and cheating to their syllabus. It works well to prevent future bad homework questions from that class and helps educate students about how not to use this site. That doesn't mean that I'll help take these questions down, though, if they happen to be on topic and have good answers.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. May I ask why some people downvoted my question (not pointing fingers, just want to know what was wrong with it)?

Comment: @DIMMSum Likely for lack of research; this is not exactly the first time that this question has been asked.

Comment: @Servy I did do research. If it was a duplicate, why did you answer the question instead of flagging it as a duplicate?

Comment: @DIMMSum - You asked for conjecture and Servy provided some, that doesn't necessarily mean he downvoted your post or that he thought it was an exact duplicate. Be careful what you ask for ;)

Comment: @TravisJ fair enough :-p

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On the site, nothing.  If you happen to know the teacher personally, you're more than welcome to contact them and point them to those questions.  As far as Stack Overflow is concerned though, whether or not your question is in line with your school's policies has no bearing on whether or not it is an appropriate question.

Comment: really so we(you) are ok with questions that violate "rules" of various types? what about country laws?

Comment: @Dagon:  We're quite powerless to enforce these rules without having direct contact with the institution anyway, so Servy's advice of, "If you know them personally, report it" is about the best you can do.

Comment: @Dagon It's not our duty to enforce them.  It's best left to those that *are* there to enforce them.  We couldn't consistently do so even if we wanted to.

Comment: threes quite a lot of power users with certain rep have. so they are quite enforceable by the S.O community

Comment: @Dagon The point is that you can't necessarily *know* when a post violates some private institutions internal rules, or some country's laws.

Comment: in some case you can know, whats your(the) policy then?

Comment: @Dagon which country?  There are 196 of them.  Should we enforce the laws of all of them?  And what about the laws that contradict another country's laws.  As indicated, we shouldn't make ourselves the enforcers of any laws or rules beyond those that exist on this site.  Specific complaints about specific posts should be directed at Stack Exchange by someone who can enforce such rules

Comment: @Dagon [This is the policy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338778/1159478)

Comment: Um @Dagon  keep it focused please. That is unnecessary.

Comment: its a meta "discussion" regarding outside rules. S.O does not live in its own universe.

Comment: @Dagon No, it doesn't, but that doesn't mean that SO is obligated to enforce every single rule of every single public and private entity in the world.  It couldn't even if it wanted to.  If you want to run your own Q/A site you're more than welcome to enforce the rules of every single entity on the planet there, if that's what you want to do (best of luck trying).

Comment: @Dagon Why is SO obligated to *try* to enforce every rule of every public and private entity on the planet?

Comment: @Dagon I don't think you understand the moral implications of trying to enforce the rules of every single law of every country and every single rule of every single private entity on the planet.  You realize that there are a lot of countries with a lot of *extremely* immoral laws (by most people's standards), and a lot of private entities with a *lot* of *very* immoral rules.  Do we enforce the KKK's rules on what race of people can have questions answered?  Do we prohibit questions relating to topics that North Korea consider defamatory to their world view?

Comment: If SO is completely agonstic to outside policies, then it seems like the policy I quoted (*If there are specific restrictions (for example, you can receive help, but not full code samples), include them in the question so that those providing assistance can keep you out of trouble*) should be amended. That policy seems to suggest that SO does have some stake regarding what questions should and should not be answered aside from the quality and relevance of the question itself.

Comment: @dimmsum as mentioned in that post, that is not an official policy persay, but community accepted moderation guidelines. That phrase is for reminding the student to be aware of their schools policy

Comment: @dagon it's not about sticking your head in the sand. Each thing in its place(lfor instance stack is not a place to enforce school rules). Some rules for different countries/school might actually CONTRADICT one another. How can we make the distinction? Has nothing to do with morals or ethics here. Simply practicality.

Comment: @Dagon If I recall correctly, google is banned in China. Should questions about google products be off-topic? That would include the entire Go language, as well as many other commonly used API's. Facebook was banned in Pakistan for a short period of time, should all questions about Facebook have been off-topic during that time? Many countries have banned high-powered lasers... well that has nothing to do with programming, but regardless!

Comment: @DIMMSum The section that you quoted says that if the author of the question is encouraged to include, in the question, restrictions that may be placed on them in order for them to stay in line with their schools policies.  This means that conscientious answerers will be able to stay in line with them, if they want.  Nowhere in there does it say that the site's moderation policies will actively enforce those policies, deleting answers that aren't in line with it, etc., merely that including the information will often be useful, for those who are interested in it.