# How should I review / vote on the Answers to Low-Quality Questions

Tags: discussion

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564617/displaying-a-specific-amount-of-strings-out-of-an-arraylist-in-java), which is quite blatently homework.  I then tried to find a hard policy on homework, which, given the polarity of the community about homework questions, I was surprised to not find.  The best I found was [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) meta post.

So in context of the question, we have a user who quite clearly gave a poorly-asked homework question.  It does literally none of the things listed in the meta post, and has every indication that the asker is just asking for code so they do not have to try.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48564709/1601729), on the other hand, is clear in its functionality, and I feel very legible for someone who is learning.  It also provides a (brief) explanation of what's happening.  I don't think it's generally a bad answer.  But it's also giving away the solution when the asker (I feel) should've been instructed to put more effort into the question before just being handed the answer.

Perhaps I'm imposing my own opinions on the matter, but is the answer good if it rewards asking very low-quality questions?
 How should I evaluate this answer?

Comment: I would close that Q as 'Too broad', (if I had not made this comment on meta).  That, or asking for tuition, or unclear.  I suspect that the Q. will be closed, and probably deleted.   SO should not be teaching basic flow control mechanisms like loops:(

Comment: Last I checked(which admittedly was in 2013), the policy on homework was to treat it no differently from anything else.

Comment: @SamIam I initially had the question geared towards homework, but the point I'm trying to make is about low-quality questions more so than homework (I just have homework questions mentally registered as synonymous with low-quality questions at this point, given how frequently it seems to be true).  There can be high-quality homework questions which answers to can be useful for, for sure.

Comment: The duplicate mark is fair.  I looked for "review answers to low-quality questions" and "review answers to homework questions".  I've accepted it, but will leave the question standing because I feel like the different keywords will increase visibility if others search for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Perhaps I'm imposing my own opinions on the matter

That's literally what votes are for.  They *exist* for you to express your own opinion on whether or not you think the answer is a useful answer.  If you think that providing a code dump to the question isn't useful (an opinion many others, including me, share) you're *encouraged* to reflect that opinion in your vote.  If you feel that it's beneficial to the programming community to have a code dump provided to this homework question (an opinion also shared by many people in the community) you're encouraged to reflect *that* in your vote.

Don't vote based on whether or not *other* people think the answer is useful, vote on whether or not *you* think the answer is useful.  The net score of the post will then reflect the overall opinion of the community, rather than any one voter.

Comment: Absolutely.  Make you own anaysis of the question, how diligently it was researched, whether it's highly likely to be a dupe, it's usefulness to future SO users/vistors.

Comment: +1, but, just to clarify; I do feel like the answer is just adequate *in a vacuum*.  My concern is the answer *in relation to the question*.  I'm questioning if it is reasonable to penalize an answer because it's handing a low-quality no-effort question the answer it sought out, rather than getting them to design a proper question (including putting an acceptable amount of work in).

Comment: @Ironcache So you think that it's likely that other people will have this problem, find this question, read the answer, and solve their problem as a result?  If so, then you think the answer is helpful.  If you think that, for whatever reason, that's unlikely to happen say, because the quality problems in the question prevent others with the problem from finding it, or because there's a million other questions with this information out there that others will find instead, or because this isn't a problem others could possibly have, etc. then that would mean the post *isn't* helpful.

Comment: So it's not about whether or not the question has problems, it's about whether the quality problems with the question prevent the answer from being useful.  *Most* of the time, they will (because we *define* problems with the question as things that make answers to them not be useful, more or less).  But if a question has problems that still result in an answer being a quality discoverable solution to a problem not previously having a discoverable quality solution (which, again, should be pretty rare) then there's no reason to reflect that in the answer's vote.