# New question close option

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, homework

Nowadays, many questions on Stack Overflow are nothing but a homework dump. But there is no proper option to close such questions. These are the existing close options:

- Duplicate - This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
- A community-specific reason - This question doesn’t meet a Stack Overflow guideline.
- Needs details or clarity - This question should include more details and clarify the problem.
- Needs more focus - This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.
- Opinion-based - This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

**I would like Stack Overflow to add an option like this:**

- Homework dump - Honest attempt to solve the problem has not been made by the OP

Comment: Why that downvote? Isn't my request valid?

Comment: _Needs more focus / details_ pick one.

Comment: But that does not mean the same as *homework dump*

Comment: And how does that matter? That _HW dumps_ should be extraordinarily VLQ content?

Comment: If the reason does not matter, then y do u give ppl options when they vote to close a question? Just a close button would be sufficient.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, then why do u close it? After all, a duplicate question is not *bad*

Comment: Duplicates should be closed because otherwise the information becomes sparse - you may end up having tens, or hundreds of answers on different questions which are the same, then you have to go searching for the one that works for you. Then if the way to do something changes (new technologies, etc.) updating all those answers is very difficult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Not really. Looks like I have created a record for the most no.of downvotes! Lol. This won't affect my SO profile, right?

Comment: @Sushil, No, votes on Meta sites are separate from votes on main sites. Voting on Meta is different than on main sites. While votes on Meta do, potentially, reflect similar quality issues as voting on main, votes on Meta are largely used as indicating agreement or disagreement.

Comment: Ok...BTW, is there something wrong with my post? Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @Sushil Your proposal has missed a few issues. The functional ones are A) We can't change the list of close reasons on the popup page you've shown. The close reasons there are global to all Stack Exchange sites. B) We can change most of the close reasons on the page which opens when "A community-specific reason" is clicked. However, only 5 slots are available on that page. Thus, to add one, another must be removed. Any proposal for change should include what you propose to remove to allow adding. Generally, only the most commonly used are kept, leaving everything else to a custom reason.

Comment: As to why so many downvotes, the most likely reason is that people just disagree with the proposal. Downvotes are the primary way people express disagreement with a post on Meta. What to do with homework questions is something of a controversial issue. There's bound to be disagreement with almost any proposal. However, you don't appear to have looked at what discussions have already happened, so you're running into the issue without having taken a look at where you're stepping. That's bound result in running into some obstacles.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Homework dumps are not off-topic. if you can't find other reason for the question to be unsuitable for the site besides being homework, why close it?

"Lack of attempt" is not a close reason. If anything, it's a downvote reason. The close reasons you are looking for have to do with a question not being adequately scoped, not being clear enough, or missing details. Many of those things **can be (and often are) related** to not putting the appropriate amount of effort and research, but that's all. In the end those are distinct categories.

> If a question is a duplicate, then why do u close it? After all, a duplicate question is not bad

We close a question as a duplicate to help the asker and future visitors find the right answer. Not because duplicate questions are bad or off-topic

Comment: I agree with that. One issue is that a new trend appears, marking as duplicate questions without enough effort, the pseudo duplicate being a post giving general good advices to beginner. I feel rather uncomfortable with that, as it seems to break the SO *duplicate* system. An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64701825/10553341)

Comment: The choice is essentially between closing **immediately** with a Dupe vote (for the hammer bearers) and leaving a crappy question open that might attract answers it does not deserve. If we close immediately and DV, it gets rooma'd that much quicker as I recall.

Comment: For homework questions, the [on-topic page](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says: "Questions asking for homework help must include [A] a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and [B] a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." Many people consider "a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem" to mean that an attempt must be shown. While that's usually what it equates to, an attempt isn't *necessarily* required. What's required for (A) is a summary of any work already done. If they've done nothing, then they need to say that.

Comment: That's the prob. The post would have nothing but a one-page long paragraph that has just been lifted from the textbook. No attempts or nothing. That's the sole reason behind why I am requesting for this feature.

Comment: @Sushil I think you're still missing the point. No effort is a *downvote* reason, **not** a *close* reason. Questions should be closed if they are a duplicate, off-topic, poorly defined, or missing necessary details. Homework questions *may, but not always* fall into these categories, and should be judged simply on their merit, not their origin.