# Comments about the Satisfaction Survey

Tags: discussion, question-quality, survey, homework

I filled out the satisfaction survey, but my answers are not going to be particularly useful, because the problems I have with Stack Overflow are mostly things that are not under the site's control.  So, I'm going to explain myself and hope someone who cares sees this.

I've been answering technical questions online for 35 or 40 years, first on [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) newsgroups, then on [CompuServe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompuServe), then on Microsoft's mailing lists and forums.  I'm a respected authority on Windows drivers.  I was a Microsoft "[Most Valued Professional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Most_Valuable_Professional)" (MVP) for 23 consecutive years, until they decided the MVPs needed to be an unpaid marketing intern staff instead of a reward for helping out.  I've been answering questions here for about five months and I enjoy it.

The only complaint I have about the site is that I can't format code in comments.  That's an extremely minor issue, and I've started using GitHub gists when I need a snippet longer than a few lines, but it is inconvenient.

The bigger issue I have is with the quality of the questions, and there's little anyone here can do about that.  A large fraction of the questions are students who just post homework questions verbatim, without offering any of their own work, and often without even adding an introduction.  Can it possibly be the case that personal ethics is just not a concern for most of the world?  I find that very discouraging.

Another large fraction of the questions are people trying to build websites by scraping information from other websites, trying to work around barriers that were placed specifically to prevent people from stealing copyrighted information.  I find the mention of "anti-captcha" sites to be very distasteful, and although I've answered many [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) questions, I'm always going to point out why it is not entirely ethical.

Overall, I've felt welcome and appreciated in my few months on Stack Overflow, and although the points don't matter (like on Whose Line), they're nice to have.

I suppose this is actually a poor post for Meta, since I haven't really asked a question. It's not really a place for op-eds.  Close it, if that's best for the community.

Comment: you should consider yourself lucky to have both received the survey and being allowed to complete it

Comment: While you don't seem to invite much discussion immediately from the post, the fact you use it to express disappointment about poor quality of posts instead of extreme moderation pleases me greatly.

Comment: You can  leverrage your reviews maybe? If we close the many low quality questions new users might not feel endorsed to post their zero-effort dump.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question doesn't appear to be seeking any input or discussion from the community. It's basically just a rant, which you're aware of, given the tag you've added. It's a well written rant, and given your stance, you're going to get a lot of agreement, and sympathy (and upvotes) from the Meta regulars. Nonetheless, this seems to be off-topic to me, so I'm going to vote to close it as such. Please feel free to edit it in a way that actually invites discussion.

Comment: Well @cigien re-introducing the rant tag is maybe suboptimal but please enlighten me a bit what the problem is? Is it the ethical aspect that focusses on users instead of content?

Comment: @rene Well, like I said, I'm not sure what the question is here. It seems to be an opinion piece, which is off-topic on Meta right? There is a question "*Can it possibly be the case that personal ethics is just not a concern for most of the world?*", but I don't really see how that's something useful to discuss here. I could be wrong of course; maybe this post is fine because we all sort of agree with the opinion?

Comment: While the satisfaction survey may have spurred your interest in making this post and providing this feedback, i don't think it adequately describes your post. Your post focuses on several topics that are each quite complex on their own, and have each been discussed at length here before (that doesn't mean we can't have a discussion on them again, if we aren't re-treading existing ground) but otherwise it doesn't really matter in the end, as feedback on meta isn't often taken into account for site changes.

Comment: TLDR don't hope for feedback to be read and affect change, be part of the solution.

Comment: I can't disagree with the criticism.  If it gets closed, I'm not going to pout.

Comment: The [meta-tag:ethics] tag might have useful guidance on how to deal / what our position is wrt the scraping questions.

Comment: And for the homework stuff: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: problem is: You and I now have read these posts. Now we need those new users to do the same and proceed from there on the right direction.

Comment: Well @cigien there is a very, very, very, small difference between *just a rant* and *an opinion piece* but I'm glad I asked as your second comment clearly strikes a better tone then the first one.  Any improvement is good I guess.

Comment: @rene Ah, I see. You're right, I could have phrased it better than *basically just a rant*. I don't really see a rant as a negative thing *per se*, because rants can be presented well, as is done in this case, but it does have mostly negative connotations, which I should have realized when I made my first comment.

Comment: In regards to your smaller complaint about code in comments, I would argue that if takes more than a few line of code, it is probably better to have as an answer than a comment. For one or two lines, the `code_backticks` seem to do a sufficient job.

Comment: You ***could*** ask a question (such as, *"How can I find more interesting questions to answer? I am being drowned out by unpaid (and [paid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiverr)) do-homework dumps."*). Or a make feature request (such as, *"Can we pretty please raise the barrier to entry by adding a vetting stage before blasting out questions onto the public Internet?"* or *"Implement features that bring back the FAQ writing culture of Usenet. (And change the gamification to* ***not*** encourage answering hyper super mega duplicate questions.)"*).

Comment: @PeterMortensen probably duplicates of existing questions. None of those topics sound unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @Tyberius Ah, I have gone round and round with myself about that.  There are just too many cases were I can offer a rewrite that will help guide towards an answer, but doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @rene: The FAQ writing part is weak. There are some attempts in some tag wikis, but it is lacking, e.g. in visibility. There is also the technical limitations of too little space (to contain a sufficiently high number of (real) FAQs to be effective).

Comment: @TimRoberts Even so an answer that leads someone to the answer, is more an answer than a comment. Plus you get the added *bonus* of fake internet points to make you feel good about yourself. Seriously though, allowing extended code in comments is a bad idea, please don't suggest it. What's wrong with leaving an answer if it doesn't help the OP directly if it might help someone else at the end of the day?

Comment: Yea, i mean, what's the harm in just calling this place a help desk, it is what it is

Comment: I was writing this as an answer when the question got closed... If a comment needs more than one or two lines of code, it is probably better presented as an answer. An answer has the advantage that it can be edited for more than five minutes after it is submitted. Also, for code which takes meaning from indentation, such as Python, the formatting available in an answer compared to a comment is pretty much essesntial.

Comment: I disagree with *The bigger issue I have is with the quality of the questions, and there's little anyone here can do about that.* It would well be within the site's control to increase the barrier to entry, which could likely cut the (very sizeable) proportion of horrendous or off-topic questions a number of percentage points. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903 But fewer questions means fewer eyes on ads, which SE Inc would not want.