# Is it unfriendly to ask an OP if they want us to write code / homework for them?

Tags: discussion, comments

If an OP posts a question that does not demonstrate too much effort / research,
would it be considered unfriendly if in a comment I ask them:

```
"You want us to write code for you?"
```

or

```
"Do you expect us to solve your homework for you?"
```

If they say "yes, write the code for me", then we can know that this question can be deleted immediately (and save everyone time), or am I mistaken?

[image]

Comment: A comment like that is, at best, rhetorical. What sort of a response do you expect from an OP to a comment like that? Whether it's unfriendly or not, it's an entirely unproductive comment, and those are best avoided.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it unfriendly, but I also wouldn't consider it useful.

Comment: if they say "yes, write the code for me", then we can know that this question can be deleted immediately, or am i mistaken?

Comment: I would suggest linking them to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) - that is more actionable by the OP.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff and if they say "no" (many do, when faced with this question) or don't answer at all, what then?

Comment: @VLAZ then we know that this question has potential and it deserves a chance

Comment: What the op wants, isn't relevant. We aren't here to serve the op. If the question can be a useful Q/A pair with an answer, even if the op doesn't have the skills themselves to implement it, it's still a useful Q/A pair.

Comment: If an OP says "yes", the question may still be on-topic if it's a narrowly scoped, programming question. All you've told us here is that the OP has not put in research effort, which in and of itself, is not a reason to close, or delete a question.

Comment: Important is: Is the question itself suitable for SO? It's about the content, not the user (unless in special cases of abuse like serial spammers).

Comment: *"or am i mistaken?"* Yes, in a sense. You could possibly VTC as "unclear" or "too broad" if they are applicable, but if you want to be helpful you could also direct them to the relevant [help] articles, possibly the [tour], and/or an FAQ Q&A here on meta. Voting to delete, before the question is closed or even the OP has been asked to "fix" the question is wrong though. Most likely though what you should be doing is downvoting and moving on.

Comment: We should be evaluating the question by the actual question. If the OP asks "How do I write an entire OS" that's too broad and closeable, regardless of whether or not they want *us* to write the OS. If they ask how to do a something covered by a common duplicate, we again should close it against the duplicate. Regardless of whether OP wants *us* to write the code  or not.

Comment: Seems OK to ask a clarifying question as long as you can ask it politely. Whether "You want us to write code for you?" is polite enough is subjective.

Comment: i added a snip demonstrating this situation

Comment: That [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69224521/2029983) is clearly too broad/lacks focus, @DennisKozevnikoff . It doesn't matter if the OP wants us to "write them the codes", the fact is that they haven't asked a clear and specific programming question.

Comment: You have taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you know that "...we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." It's not supposed to be a help desk. If the OP wants others to write code, the question *may* need details or clarity or more focus, but not necessarily.

Comment: What's problematic is a lot of people post comments like this on questions where, Yes, they want us to provide the solution *and there's nothing wrong with that* in some cases. Don't force a potential useful question into becoming a useless debugging question.

Comment: @Larnu I agree, I don't see how an answer of "no" by the OP would have made this question have potential and be worthwhile.

Comment: It often gets parroted around here that "we're not a code writing service". However, we're in the business of providing useful answers to programming questions, which... *usually include code*. We are _absolutely_ a code writing service in that fashion, and if anyone asks a (high-quality, on-topic) question which is best answered by code, there is *zero* problem with them having the expectation that we'll "write code for them".

Comment: I read both example questions as (intentional) [rhetorical questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question). Is that your intent or not? Can you clarify in your question?

Comment: @zcoop98 we do write code but we're not here to produce code one can just take and have a finished product. The majority of the code we produce is illustrative "Given parameters A and B, we can apply X and Y in a fashion similar to this". So, we're not a code writing service as in we're not here to write all the code the question asker needs. We provide enough to let them get on with their task.

Comment: Maybe we should go old school and and ignore the student until they have demonstrated they have the patience and grit to use our teachings wisely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is unfriendly.

You are basically trying to trick OP into saying the wrong thing, and if he does, you close his question. I can't see how one could consider this as friendly.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you. However such questions are probably better off deleted ASAP, to save everybody time.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff But you don’t need the OP to say anything about what they’re expecting in order to close/delete an off topic question.

Answer (score 13):

Don't bother commenting.  Just flag/vote to close accordingly if the question is overly broad.

By commentating you put a big ol' target on your back.  It's not worth the trouble to try to "guide" the OP on this; let the system handle that much.

Comment: I assume by "commentating" you mean "commenting "?

Comment: It's commentating.

Comment: I just googled it, and it turns out you are correct, there is such a word!

Comment: (*[commentating](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commentate#Verb)* - *"Sometimes proscribed as an unnecessary or uneducated backformation, with* ***comment*** *and* ***provide commentary*** *preferred."*)