# Not all off-topic reasons flaggable?

Tags: discussion, flags, homework

I know there's already a meta post about how to handle homework questions: [Please clarify the policy on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions)
But my question is a little different I think.

I've read [the possible reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a question being off-topic:

> 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")...
> 2. Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error...
> 3. **Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.**
> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource...
> 5. Questions about general computing hardware and software...
> 6. Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration...

There are many homework-dumping questions on SO that show no research effort and I'd like to flag them for reason number **3**. Looking at the flag dialog, there is no option for that:

[image]

Why is it, that I can flag a question for the five other reasons, but not this one? It seems like an *inconsistency* to me, given that there are six possible off-topic reasons described on the help page.

Comment: That's long time gone now.

Comment: You can usually also flag most of those questions as either missing an MCVE, unclear what you're asking or as too broad. Therefore, I don't really see a need for another flag/close option.

Comment: If the question is too broad, unclear, or off-topic for any other reason, close it for that reason. Don't just run for the close vote button because it looks like it might be a homework assignment. A lot of those questions are actually on-topic.

Comment: Yep, this should be removed from the help centre if it isn't a close reason in it's own right any more or it should be added as a close reason.

Comment: @rene -  I see guidance on asking, answering and voting on homework questions in that duplicate target but not on voting to close them - which is the topic of the question here.

Comment: @MartinSmith fair enough. One other issue: Why didn't that ping me? I thought the dupe-hammers are pingable on a question they closed? I didn't get a notification in my inbox ...

Comment: @rene Hmmm I don't know why it didn't ping you. I see I edited the comment but I don't remember what edit I made - If I edited the `@rene` in afterwards maybe that wouldn't ping? I'll try editing the `@rene` into this one too.

Comment: @MartinSmith your original comment did at rene - it's not that

Comment: I got that last one @MartinSmith so ... let's keep it on some Unicorns on the wire ...

Comment: Once you get to 3k rep, you can write in a custom close reason instead of raising one of the stock flags. It's quite useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good catch!

I've edited out reference to the homework close reason on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: But every question should include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Those are the 2 of the 3 pillars of  of asking a descriptive, well researched question: context, context and context.

Comment: Removing the reason was the wrong thing to do, better to remove just the words "asking for homework help".

Comment: The *homework* reason is back - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344563/not-all-off-topic-reasons-flaggable/344641#344641

Comment: Yep, it's back.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by some of the other answers, that's not a list of flag reasons or close reasons it's a guidance list of what's on/off-topic on Stack Overflow.  The [Asking page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) contains guidance on what topics can be asked on Stack Overflow.  There are also many types of questions which are off-topic on Stack Overflow and the list presents some examples - it does not need to match the list of reasons presented on the flag/close dialog.

Users are presented with links to asking help while they formulate the question and including a little blip about homework is used to explain what is needed when asking that type of question.  We don't specifically have a close reason for homework questions; homework questions are allowed on Stack Overflow if the user [follows a few guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

We might need to clarify that page to include some details about dealing with homework, but it's important to include it, so for the time-being I've added that bit back into the Help Center page.

Answer (score 7):

Two of those bullet points are about quality, not topic scope.  The reason they're listed on the on-topic FAQ page is because, like the other bullets, they carve out exceptions to the general policy of "If it's on-topic, you can ask".

Failure to clearly state a specific problem (mentioned in both the debugging and homework bullets) is expected to result in closure as "Unclear what you're asking", which is found as a sibling to "Off-topic", not a subitem.

Honestly, voting/flagging to close and selecting the "off-topic: questions seeking debugging help" reason ought to be counted toward "unclear what you're asking", and the associated explanation ought to be expanded to cover not only MCVE but also desired vs. observed results.

---

[image: The top-level close reasons]

Answer (score -3):

The text wasn't a one to one relationship to close reasons. It is expected to give guidance to the people asking question, in particular those that happen to have questions about their homework. Stack Overflow requires you to include some context, to be able to clear up your doubts at the same time of creating a repository of accurate, authoritative answers to unique software development questions. That's what sets SO apart of the average.

The text was aimed as a pointed recommendation to those having troubles with their homework. SO never had a off topic reason that reads like that. It just happen to be that the other points in the same section also has specific off topic reasons on the main site (at least one of them was added recently MCVE).

All questions should include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. If someone that is about to ask a question reads that and make sure their question fits the tally, it tend to perform better than those that do not.